# How do I query using fields inside the new PostgreSQL JSON datatype?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, postgresql-9.2, postgresql-9.3

I am looking for some docs and/or examples for the new JSON functions in PostgreSQL 9.2.

Specifically, given a series of JSON records:

```
[
  {name: "Toby", occupation: "Software Engineer"},
  {name: "Zaphod", occupation: "Galactic President"}
]
```

How would I write the SQL to find a record by name?

In vanilla SQL:

```
SELECT * from json_data WHERE "name" = "Toby"
```

The official dev manual is quite sparse:

- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/datatype-json.html
- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/functions-json.html

#### Update I

I've put together a [gist detailing what is currently possible with PostgreSQL 9.2](https://gist.github.com/2715918).
Using some custom functions, it is possible to do things like:

```
SELECT id, json_string(data,'name') FROM things
WHERE json_string(data,'name') LIKE 'G%';
```

#### Update II

I've now moved my JSON functions into their own project:

[**PostSQL**](https://github.com/tobyhede/postsql) - a set of functions for transforming PostgreSQL and PL/v8 into a totally awesome JSON document store

Comment: Just recently I found this blog post by Matt Schinckel, which explains in detail querying JSON in PostgreSQL http://schinckel.net/2014/05/25/querying-json-in-postgres/

Comment: @knowbody This post is actually about querying JSONB, which is quite distinct from JSON. My bad for not making that clearer in the post.

Answer (score 210, accepted):

#### Postgres 9.2

I quote [Andrew Dunstan on the pgsql-hackers list](https://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-hackers/2012-01/msg01764.php):

> At some stage there will possibly be some json-processing (as opposed
> to json-producing) functions, but not in 9.2.

Doesn't prevent him from providing an example implementation in PLV8 that should solve your problem. (Link is dead now, see modern [PLV8](https://plv8.github.io/) instead.)

#### Postgres 9.3

Offers an arsenal of new functions and operators to add "json-processing".

- [The manual on new JSON functionality.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-json.html)
- [The Postgres Wiki on new features in pg 9.3](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What%27s_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.3#JSON:_Additional_functionality).

The answer to the **original question** in Postgres 9.3:

For a given table:

```
CREATE TABLE json_tbl (data json);
```

Query:

```sql
SELECT object
FROM   json_tbl
     , json_array_elements(data) AS object
WHERE  object->>'name' = 'Toby';
```

Advanced example:

- [Query combinations with nested array of records in JSON datatype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26877241/query-combinations-with-nested-array-of-records-in-json-datatype/26880705#26880705)

For bigger tables you may want to add an expression index to increase performance:

- [Index for finding an element in a JSON array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404055/index-for-finding-element-in-json-array)

#### Postgres 9.4

Adds **`jsonb`** (b for "binary", values are stored as native Postgres types) and yet more functionality for *both* types. In addition to expression indexes mentioned above, `jsonb` also supports [GIN, btree and hash indexes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/datatype-json.html#JSON-INDEXING), GIN being the most potent of these.

- The manual on [`json` and `jsonb` data types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/datatype-json.html) and [functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html).
- [The Postgres Wiki on JSONB in pg 9.4](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What%27s_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.4#JSONB_Binary_JSON_storage)

The manual goes as far as suggesting:

> In general, **most applications should prefer to store JSON data as
> `jsonb`**, unless there are quite specialized needs, such as legacy
> assumptions about ordering of object keys.

Bold emphasis mine.
Also, performance benefits from general [improvements to GIN indexes.](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What%27s_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.4#GIN_indexes_now_faster_and_smaller)

#### Postgres 9.5

Complete `jsonb` functions and operators. Add more functions to manipulate `jsonb` in place and for display.

- [Major good news in the release notes of Postgres 9.5.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/release-9-5.html#AEN126466)

Functionality and performance has been improved with every major Postgres version since. It's pretty complete by now (as of Postgres 16). One major, notable addition in ...

#### Postgres 12

... is the [SQL/JSON path language](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH) along with operators and functions. The answer to the example in the question can now be, for a given table (with `jsonb`):

```
CREATE TABLE jsonb_tbl (data jsonb);

SELECT jsonb_path_query_first(data, '$[*] ? (@.name == "Toby")') AS object
FROM   jsonb_tbl
WHERE  data @> '[{"name": "Toby"}]';  -- optional, for index support
```

Or equivalent:

```
...
WHERE  data @@ '$[*].name == "Toby"';
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/pRK2QHpQ)

See:

- [Returning JSON arrary with particular property using Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73295082/returning-json-arrary-with-particular-property-using-postgres/73297778#73297778)

About indexing:

- [Find rows containing a key in a JSONB array of records](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/130863/3684)

Comment: Thanks, I've run into type issues really fast using the PLV8 approach. Looks promising, but not really usable at the moment.

Comment: @TobyHede: Guess we'll have to wait for 9.3 then.

Comment: @JoeShaw: Thanks, I updated accordingly and added a link to the Postgres Wiki.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter if i'm looking for WHERE elem->>'correct' = 'TRUE';

and the JSON looks like this: "correct":"TRUE", what is the right way to query logical terms?

Comment: @Shiraj: Please ask the new questions as *question*. Comments are not the place.

Answer (score 123):

With Postgres 9.3+, just use the `->` operator. For example,

`SELECT data->'images'->'thumbnail'->'url' AS thumb FROM instagram;`

see http://clarkdave.net/2013/06/what-can-you-do-with-postgresql-and-json/ for some nice examples and a tutorial.

Comment: In the example above you should have a field named `data` with a JSON document: `{images:{thumbnail:{url:'thumbnail.jpg'}}}`. Let us know what your data looks like and what query is failing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22667401/postgres-json-data-type-rails-query?noredirect=1#comment34548824_22667401

Comment: How can you query if there is an array? I see the #>> operator but no clue to how to use it!

Comment: In this select query can I use wildcard? I.e `SELECT data->'%'->'thumbnail'->'url' AS thumb FROM instagram;`

Comment: @Meekohi's answer works well: specifically I did not need `::json` as described in other posts. Also note the `->` operator will throw an error if you try to access a property which does not exist (i.e. if you have staggered JSON): `ERROR:  column "jsonPropertyYouWant" does not exist`

Answer (score 26):

With postgres 9.3 use -> for object access. 4 example

seed.rb

```
se = SmartElement.new
se.data = 
{
    params:
    [
        {
            type: 1,
            code: 1,
            value: 2012,
            description: 'year of producction'
        },
        {
            type: 1,
            code: 2,
            value: 30,
            description: 'length'
        }
    ]
}

se.save
```

rails c

```
SELECT data->'params'->0 as data FROM smart_elements;
```

returns

```
                                 data
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 {"type":1,"code":1,"value":2012,"description":"year of producction"}
(1 row)
```

You can continue nesting

```
SELECT data->'params'->0->'type' as data FROM smart_elements;
```

return

```
 data
------
 1
(1 row)
```