# Updating json columns in psql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

I have a table containing a json column. The json values will look something like this:

```json
{'john': 1, 'alex' : 4, 'harry' :2}
```

If I wanted to add 1 to john, how would I go about doing this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13615760/add-element-to-json-object-in-postgres

Answer (score 3):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=54cad67661c9e0ad979f177395e987de)

```
UPDATE mytable                                    -- 6
SET mydata = jsonb_set(                           -- 4
    mydata::jsonb,                                -- 1
    '{john}',                                     -- 2
    ((mydata ->> 'john')::int + 1)::text::jsonb   -- 3
)::json;                                          -- 5
```

1. Fetch your data. If it is of type `json`, cast it into type `jsonb`
2. Path to your requested element as `text` array
3. Fetch the original value. `->>` operator returns type `text`, so to do an `integer` operation, you need to cast it into type `int`. Then add the `1`. This result must be reconverted into type `jsonb`. Unfortunately type `int` cannot be cast into type `jsonb` directly, so take the intermediate step via type `text`
4. Use `jsonb_set()` to update the JSON object specified in (1)
5. If your column is of type `json` instead of `jsonb`, cast the result back into type `json`
6. Perform the update

Comment: Thank you. What if i have a json object like this:
{'john': {'age': 1}, 'alex' : {'age': 4}, 'harry' : {'age': 2}}

Comment: It's similar. You just have to modify the path which points the object: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=55f0d456699e56e03028a7381e48af39 `jsonb_set(mydata::jsonb, '{john}', ((mydata ->> 'john')::int + 1)::text::jsonb)::json`