# How to store a date in postgresql "json" datatype for use with plv8?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, datetime

I wanted to use [Date.UTC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC) to store dates and datetimes in postgresql 9.2 "json" field, but of course it fails:

```
hp=> update formapp_record set data='{"dt": Date.UTC(120, 10, 2)}' where id=17;
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
LINE 1: update formapp_record set data='{"dt": Date.UTC(120, 10, 2)}...
                                       ^
DETAIL:  Token "Date" is invalid.
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: {"dt": Date...
```

It is possible to store the UTC timestamp directly, but then how could the decoder know that the value should decode to a date or datetime instead of an int ?

It is also possible to store the Date.UTC call as string as such:

```
update formapp_record set data='{"dt": "Date.UTC(120, 10, 2)"}' where id=17;
```

While that works, it requires 0. checking if the string starts with Date.UTC and 1. use eval in plv8

A solution would be to store some metadata like:

```
update formapp_record set data='{"dt": {"_type": "date", "_value": [120, 10, 2]}}' where id=17;
```

But that's not very "standard", it's even "hackish".

What's your take on this matter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to use Postgres's `row_to_json` function and just store your dates as timestamps and extract them to json as required. However, Tobe Hede wrote some [json functions for Postgres](https://github.com/tobyhede/postsql)  that may help and seem to be alot more complete then the 2 native options that Postgres has made available for 9.2

See post [How do I query using fields inside the new PostgreSQL JSON datatype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10560394/how-do-i-query-using-fields-inside-the-new-postgresql-json-datatype) for the thread.

Answer (score 5):

Alas, [json doesn't know anything about dates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10286204/398670).

I'd store an ISO 8601 date as a string. Yes, it's a pain. Yes, it means there's no nice standard way to tell "this is a date" vs "this is a string". IMO it's less painful than most of the other options, though.

Comment: Should it be prefixed ? like value: '_date:<isodate>' ?

Comment: @jpic That depends a lot on the consuming application. Many consumers will recognise and convert ISO 8601 dates or timestamps, and would be confused by a prefix.