# Get json value in pl/pgsql

Tags: json, postgresql

I have json string like `'{"ww":11}'`

How can i get value 11 in pl/pgsql ?

I try:

```
json_var := '{"ww":11}'::json

json_var->ww;
json_var->"ww";
json_var.ww;
```

All of this failed.

Please help!
Dmitry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `json` type is just text. The advantage of using it is syntax check. Just that.

Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10560394/131874)

Comment: but in other pl* language json field are accessable. see this example https://github.com/tobyhede/postsql/blob/master/postsql.sql

Answer (score 0):

you need to typecast it to Json in order to do that.

***select '{"ww":11}'::json->'ww' as ww_value***

returns ....

11