# How to use JSON operators on JSON typed column in postgresql 9.3

Tags: postgresql-9.3

Can anyone see why this does not work?  According to [section 9.15](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html) of the manual, the `->` operator should access elements of a JSON data type. It looks to me like although the info schema says the column is type 'json' it is still really a scalar string (note the quotes when it is displayed.)

```
postgres=# create table jtest (id serial, data json);
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# select column_name, data_type from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'jtest';
 column_name | data_type
-------------+-----------
 id          | integer
 data        | json
(2 rows)

postgres=# insert into jtest (data) values (to_json('{"k1": 1, "k2": "two"}'::text));
INSERT 0 1
postgres=# select * from jtest;
 id |              data
----+--------------------------------
  1 | "{\"k1\": 1, \"k2\": \"two\"}"
(1 row)

postgres=# select data->'k1' from jtest;
ERROR:  cannot extract element from a scalar
postgres=# select data::json->'k1' from jtest;
ERROR:  cannot extract element from a scalar
postgres=# \q
$ pg_ctl --version
pg_ctl (PostgreSQL) 9.3beta2
```

**Update:**

I found these two posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17571019/select-from-based-on-a-value-in-json-format) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10560394/how-do-i-query-using-fields-inside-the-new-postgresql-json-datatype) that indicate it should work exactly as I am doing. Just to be sure I tried this:

```
postgres=# select * from jtest where data ->> 'k2' = 'two';
ERROR:  cannot extract element from a scalar
```

Is there a build option or contrib module I need to get JSON functionality?

Answer (score 7):

It appears that my mistake was using the to_json() function when inserting the data. That resulted in a JSON-encoded *string* containing my data. I did not find anything in the postgresql docs showing how to insert JSON data, but I did eventually find this post [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/australian-technology/get-some-json-in-your-database/) that showed an example. I should have done:

```
postgres=# insert into jtest (data) values ('{"k1": 1, "k2": "two"}');
INSERT 0 1
postgres=# select * from jtest;
 id |          data
----+------------------------
  1 | {"k1": 1, "k2": "two"}
(1 row)
```

(note the lack of quotes on the value in the data column.)

Now it works:

```
postgres=# select * from jtest where data ->> 'k2' = 'two';
 id |          data
----+------------------------
  1 | {"k1": 1, "k2": "two"}
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thanks for the post; also had same problem of using to_json to convert into a json column.  I went back and used CAST(field_name as json) and everything worked as expected.