# Querying inside Postgres JSON arrays

Tags: arrays, json, mongodb, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

How would you go about searching for an element inside an array stored in a `json` column?  *(Update: Also see the 9.4 updated answer for `jsonb` columns.)*

If I have a JSON document like this, stored in a `json` column named `blob`:

```
{"name": "Wolf",
 "ids": [185603363281305602,185603363289694211]}
```

what I'd like to be able to do is something like:

```
SELECT * from "mytable" WHERE 185603363289694211 = ANY("blob"->'ids');
```

and get all matching rows out.  But this doesn't work because `"blob"->'ids'` returns JSON values, not Postgres arrays.

I'd also like to build an index on the individual IDs, if that's possible.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*The following original answer applies only for Postgres 9.3.  For a Postgres 9.4 answer, see the Update below.*

This builds on [Erwin's referenced answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18834456/156), but is a little bit more explicit to this question.

The IDs in this case are `bigint`s, so create a helper function for converting a JSON array to a Postgres `bigint` array:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION json_array_bigint(_j json)
  RETURNS bigint[] AS
$$
SELECT array_agg(elem::text::bigint)
FROM json_array_elements(_j) AS elem
$$
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```

We could just have easily (and perhaps more re-usably) returned a `text` array here instead.  I suspect indexing on `bigint` is a lot faster than `text` but I'm having a difficult time finding evidence online to back that up.

For building the index:

```
CREATE INDEX "myindex" ON "mytable" 
  USING GIN (json_array_bigint("blob"->'ids'));
```

For querying, this works and uses the index:

```
SELECT * FROM "mytable" 
  WHERE '{185603363289694211}' <@ json_array_bigint("blob"->'ids');
```

Doing this will also work for querying, but it doesn't use the index:

```
SELECT * FROM "mytable" 
  WHERE 185603363289694211 = ANY(json_array_bigint("blob"->'ids'));
```

**Update for 9.4**

Postgres 9.4 introduced the `jsonb` type.  [This is a good SO answer about `jsonb` and when you should use it over `json`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22654170/explanation-of-jsonb-introduced-by-postgresql).  In short, if you're ever querying the JSON, you should use `jsonb`.

If you build your column as `jsonb`, you can use this query:

```
SELECT * FROM "mytable"
  WHERE blob @> '{"ids": [185603363289694211]}';
```

The `@>` is Postgres' contains operator, [documented for `jsonb` here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE).
Thanks to [Alain's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30226333/156) for bringing this to my attention.

Comment: +1 Nice work. Note, if elements within the JSON arrays are not unique you might get duplicate rows in the result. And yes, processing `bigint` is generally faster than processing `text`. Also makes for a *smaller* index, but simplify `elem::text::bigint` to `elem::bigint`. BTW, no need for double-quotes around perfectly valid identifiers in Postgres.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  Unfortunately casting from `json` directly to `bigint` does not work.  I have to pass it through `text` first.

Comment: `ANY(json_array_bigint("blob"->'ids');` --> there is a `)` missing at the end

Answer (score 5):

First, try the operator [`->>`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-json.html) instead of `->` to strip the JSON layer from the array value.

Next, the **query** can work like this:
[How do I query using fields inside the new PostgreSQL JSON datatype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10560394/how-do-i-query-using-fields-inside-the-new-postgresql-json-datatype/10560761#10560761)

And **indexing** might work like this:
[Index for finding an element in a JSON array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404055/index-for-finding-element-in-json-array)

Answer (score 4):

I know it's been a while...

In postgresql-9.5, it's now possible to query it easily.

```
select '{"name": "Wolf",
         "ids": [185603363281305602,185603363289694211]}'::jsonb
       @> '{"ids":[185603363281305602]}'
```

I think you should use a `jsonb` field instead and you can index it afterward.

```
CREATE INDEX idx_gin_ids ON mytable USING gin ((blob -> 'ids'));
```

Comment: This seems to also work in Postgres 9.4.  But the caveat is that `@>` only works on `jsonb` columns, not `json` columns.  (That's probably fine, I can't think of situations in which you'd choose `json` over `jsonb`, but this question was originally asked for Postgres 9.3 which didn't yet have `jsonb`)

Comment: Also I think a better example would be `SELECT * from "mytable" WHERE blob @> '{"ids": [185603363281305602]}'`;