# Explanation of JSONB introduced by PostgreSQL

Tags: json, postgresql, nosql, postgresql-json, jsonb

PostgreSQL just introduced [JSONB](http://www.depesz.com/2014/03/25/waiting-for-9-4-introduce-jsonb-a-structured-format-for-storing-json/) in version 9.4, and it's already trending [on hacker news](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7457197). How is it different from Hstore and JSON previously present in PostgreSQL?

What are its advantages and limitations and when should someone consider using it?

Comment: From PGCon2014: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oQ1LSW31Y1A&list=PLWW0CjV-Tafa2jvcjihXwSvZZKsLAsb9Y#t=2492

Comment: @CraigRinger url is not precise enough, now, 1 year later it doesn't even point close enough to JSONB-related content.

Comment: @berkus I thought I linked to the specific post. How frustrating.

Comment: It does point to the specific video.

Answer (score 632):

First, [`hstore`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/hstore.html) is a contrib module, which only allows you to store key => value pairs, where keys and values can only be `text`s (however values can be sql `NULL`s too).

Both `json` & `jsonb` allows you to store a valid JSON *value* (defined in its [spec](http://json.org)).

F.ex. these are valid JSON representations: `null`, `true`, `[1,false,"string",{"foo":"bar"}]`, `{"foo":"bar","baz":[null]}` - `hstore` is just a little subset compared to what JSON is capable (but if you only need this subset, it's fine).

The only difference between `json` & `jsonb` is their storage:

- `json` is stored in its plain text format, while
- `jsonb` is stored in some binary representation

There are 3 major consequences of this:

- `jsonb` usually takes more disk space to store than `json` (sometimes not)
- `jsonb` takes more time to build from its input representation than `json`
- `json` operations take *significantly* more time than `jsonb` (& parsing also needs to be done each time you do some operation at a `json` typed value)

When `jsonb` will be available with a stable release, there will be two major use cases, when you can easily select between them:

1. If you only work with the JSON representation in your application, PostgreSQL is only used to store & retrieve this representation, you should use `json`.
2. If you do a lot of operations on the JSON value in PostgreSQL, or use indexing on some JSON field, you should use `jsonb`.

Comment: hi, since it has binary representation, why `jsonb` doesn't support this? `UPDATE test SET data->'a' = 123 WHERE id = 1;` from `CREATE TABLE test(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, data JSONB);`

Comment: Kokizzu, it's possible in 9.5. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What's_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.5#JSONB-modifying_operators_and_functions

Comment: Just to add, one of the reasons you might also use `json` over `jsonb` is if for legacy reasons your code consuming your `json` is dependent on the ordering of the `json` fields and they can't be reordered.

Comment: what about text vs json in this case? any significant advantage of using json, compared to the performance drawbacks?

Comment: As, for the legacy reasons: in JSON, there is no semantical difference, if an object's (table, map, hash, whatever it is call in the host language) key-value pairs are ordered differently. If you rely on that, you are actually using something different than JSON. -- For `text` vs. `json`: the latter comes with JSON validation, so upon invalid JSON, it will only fail upon inserting, instead of every time your application reads it (because it gets an invalid representation). Also, you can safely cast the latter to `jsonb` within the database.

Comment: This is a great post on explaining the implementation details for JSONB (http://pgeoghegan.blogspot.com/2014/03/what-i-think-of-jsonb.html)

Comment: @geoboy It is an advantage in sense of having a dedicated query syntax so you can filter the records and avoid parsing on yourself. When you use a simple text column, you have to load all objects into the memory so you can parse it (or you could write a procedure).

Comment: Side note: SQLite says _their_ `jsonb` is usually 5-10% _smaller_ than `json`.  Different encoding from PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 189):

Peeyush:

The short answer is:

- If you are doing a lot of JSON manipulation *inside* PostgreSQL, such as sorting, slicing, splicing, etc., you should use JSONB for speed reasons.
- If you need indexed lookups for arbitrary key searches on JSON, then you should use JSONB.
- If you are doing neither of the above, you should probably use JSON.
- If you need to preserve key ordering, whitespace, and duplicate keys, you should use JSON.

For a longer answer, you'll need to wait for me to do a full "HowTo" writeup closer to the 9.4 release.

Answer (score 131):

A simple explanation of the difference between json and jsonb ([original image by PostgresProfessional](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAskN.jpg)):

```
SELECT '{"c":0,   "a":2,"a":1}'::json, '{"c":0,   "a":2,"a":1}'::jsonb;

          json          |        jsonb 
------------------------+--------------------- 
 {"c":0,   "a":2,"a":1} | {"a": 1, "c": 0} 
(1 row)
```

- json: textual storage «as is»
- jsonb: no whitespaces
- jsonb: no duplicate keys, last key wins
- jsonb: keys are sorted

More in [speech video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2dQjfdXxtJw) and [slide show presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/codefest/1bartunov-j-squery) by jsonb developers. Also they introduced *JsQuery*, a pg.extension that provides the powerful jsonb query language.

Answer (score 67):

- `hstore` is more of a "wide column" storage type, it is a flat (non-nested) dictionary of key-value pairs, always stored in a reasonably efficient binary format (a hash table, hence the name).
- `json` stores JSON documents as text, performing validation when the documents are stored, and parsing them on output if needed (i.e. accessing individual fields); it should support the entire JSON spec. Since the entire JSON text is stored, its formatting is preserved.
- `jsonb` takes shortcuts for performance reasons: JSON data is parsed on input and stored in binary format, key orderings in dictionaries are not maintained, and neither are duplicate keys. Accessing individual elements in the JSONB field is fast as it doesn't require parsing the JSON text all the time. On output, JSON data is reconstructed and initial formatting is lost.

IMO, there is no significant reason for *not* using `jsonb` once it is available, if you are working with machine-readable data.

Answer (score 62):

JSONB is a "better" version of JSON.

Let's look at an example:

```sql
SELECT '{"c":0,   "a":2,"a":1}'::json, '{"c":0,   "a":2,"a":1}'::jsonb;
```

```
          json          |        jsonb 
------------------------+--------------------- 
 {"c":0,   "a":2,"a":1} | {"a": 1, "c": 0} 
(1 row)
```

1. JSON stores white space, and that is why we can see spaces when key "a" is stored, while JSONB does not.
2. JSON stores all the values of a key. This is the reason you can see multiple values (2 and 1) against the key "a" , while JSONB only "stores" the last value.
3. JSON maintains the order in which elements are inserted, while JSONB maintains the "sorted" order.
4. JSONB objects are stored as a decompressed binary as opposed to "raw data" in JSON, where no reparsing of data is required during retrieval.
5. JSONB also supports indexing, which can be a significant advantage.

In general, one should prefer JSONB, unless there are specialized needs, such as legacy assumptions about ordering of object keys.

Answer (score 35):

Regarding the differences between `json` and `jsonb` datatypes, it worth mentioning the official explanation:

> PostgreSQL offers two types for storing JSON data: `json` and `jsonb`. To
> implement efficient query mechanisms for these data types, PostgreSQL
> also provides the jsonpath data type described in [Section 8.14.6](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#DATATYPE-JSONPATH).
>
> The `json` and `jsonb` data types accept almost identical sets of values
> as input. The major practical difference is one of efficiency. The
> `json` data type stores an exact copy of the input text, which
> processing functions must reparse on each execution; while `jsonb` data
> is stored in a decomposed binary format that makes it slightly slower
> to input due to added conversion overhead, but significantly faster to
> process, since no reparsing is needed. `jsonb` also supports indexing,
> which can be a significant advantage.
>
> Because the `json` type stores an exact copy of the input text, it will
> preserve semantically-insignificant white space between tokens, as
> well as the order of keys within JSON objects. Also, if a JSON object
> within the value contains the same key more than once, all the
> key/value pairs are kept. (The processing functions consider the last
> value as the operative one.) By contrast, `jsonb` does not preserve
> white space, does not preserve the order of object keys, and does not
> keep duplicate object keys. If duplicate keys are specified in the
> input, only the last value is kept.
>
> In general, most applications should prefer to store JSON data as
> `jsonb`, unless there are quite specialized needs, such as legacy
> assumptions about ordering of object keys.
>
> PostgreSQL allows only one character set encoding per database. It is
> therefore not possible for the JSON types to conform rigidly to the
> JSON specification unless the database encoding is UTF8. Attempts to
> directly include characters that cannot be represented in the database
> encoding will fail; conversely, characters that can be represented in
> the database encoding but not in UTF8 will be allowed.

Source: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html

Answer (score 21):

I was at the [PostgresOpen](https://2019.postgresopen.org/about/) today, and benchmarks are way faster than [MongoDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MongoDB). I believe it was around 500% faster for selects. Pretty much everything was faster, at least by at 200% when contrasted with MongoDB. Then one exception right now is an update which requires completely rewriting the entire JSON column - something MongoDB handles better.

The gin indexing on JSONB sounds amazing.

Also PostgreSQL will persist types of JSONB internally and basically match this with types such as numeric, text, boolean, etc.

Joins will also be possible using JSONB.

Add PLv8 for stored procedures and this will basically be a dream come true for [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) developers.

Being it's stored as binary, JSONB will also strip all white space, change the ordering of properties and remove duplicate properties using the last occurrence of the property.

Besides the index when querying against a JSONB column contrasted to a JSON column PostgreSQL doesn't have to actually run the functionality to convert the text to JSON on every row which will likely save a vast amount of time alone.

Answer (score 10):

Another important difference, that wasn't mentioned in any answer above, is that there is no equality operator for `json` type, but there is one for `jsonb`.

This means that you can't use `DISTINCT` keyword when selecting this `json`-type and/or other fields from a table (you can use `DISTINCT ON` instead, but it's not always possible because of cases like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9795660/postgresql-distinct-on-with-different-order-by)).

Answer (score 8):

As far as I can tell,

- hstore as it currently exists (in PostgreSQL 9.3) does not allow for nesting other objects and arrays as the values of its key/value pairs. However, a future hstore patch will allow for nesting. This patch will not be in the 9.4 release and may not be included any time soon.
- json as it currently exists *does* allow for nesting, but it is text-based and does not allow for indexing, thus it is "slow"
- jsonb that will be released with 9.4 will have the current nesting capabilities of json, as well as the GIN/GIST indexing of hstore, so it will be fast

People working on PostgreSQL 9.4 seem to be saying that the new, fast jsonb type will appeal to people who would have chosen to use a [NoSQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) data store like [MongoDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MongoDB), but it can now combine a relational database with query-able unstructured data under one roof

*[Why HStore2/jsonb is the most important patch of 9.4](http://www.databasesoup.com/2014/02/why-hstore2jsonb-is-most-important.html)*

Benchmarks of PostgreSQL 9.4 jsonb seem to be on par with or in some cases faster than MongoDB.

http://texture.io/alphabetum/postgresql-incl-hstore-vs-mongodb

Comment: The last link is broken: *"DisallowedHost at /alphabetum/postgresql-incl-hstore-vs-mongodb"*