# JSONB object field as number or boolean (without text-casting need)

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

Now with a [complete JSON operator set in pg9.4](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html)  and JSONB type, is expected to be use JSONB as a part of "PostgreSQL algebra"... Not JSONB as an "isolated universe"...

In performance terms, JSONB is faster than JSON, because is internally  "more strongly typed" than JSON... As [remembered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22910602/287948), *"JSON operations take significantly more time than JSONB"*.  So JSONB can be faster in type casting of its boolean, integer and number types... Let's go... **We can't, why not?**

---

MOTIVATION

Need a function as `get_jsonb_value(jsonb,field,type)` (or a set of functions like `jbval_to_int()`, `jbval_to_float()`,`jbval_to_boolean()`), to use the JSONB internal representation, and do a faster casting.

---

EDIT

If that kind of function (see [formal requeriment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Requirements_analysis) examples below) not exist in the PostgreSQL Guide (**there exist similar thing?**) and it is not in a "next pg version" (**it is a planed feature?**)... Them, the question is **"how to implement it in C, taking advantage of the internal JSONB representation?"**

```
CREATE FUNCTION jbval_to_numeric(JSONB, varchar) RETURNS numeric AS $f$
  SELECT CASE 
    WHEN jsonb_typeof($1->$2)='number' THEN ($1->>$2)::numeric
    ELSE NULL::numeric 
  END;
$f$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;

CREATE FUNCTION jbval_to_float(JSONB, varchar) RETURNS float AS $f$
  SELECT CASE 
    WHEN jsonb_typeof($1->$2)='number' THEN ($1->>$2)::float
    ELSE NULL::float
  END;
$f$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;

CREATE FUNCTION jbval_to_int(JSONB, varchar, boolean DEFAULT true) 
RETURNS int AS $f$
  SELECT CASE 
    WHEN jsonb_typeof($1->$2)='number' THEN 
       CASE WHEN $3 THEN ($1->>$2)::int ELSE ($1->>$2)::float::int END
    ELSE NULL::int
  END;
$f$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;

CREATE FUNCTION jbval_to_boolean(JSONB, varchar) RETURNS boolean AS $f$
  SELECT CASE 
    WHEN jsonb_typeof($1->$2)='boolean' THEN ($1->>$2)::boolean
    ELSE NULL::boolean 
  END;
$f$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Is about 1) the PostgreSQL guide, where this function?  ... if this functio really not exists, is about 2) best way to implement that kind of function... Perhaps need C implementation.

Comment: I don't know ... which function ... you mean ... You do know... that all functions ... are documented ... in the ... manual? If ... a function ...  isn't documented there ... then it doesn't exist ...

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The PostgreSQL Guide is so big and some confuse, I need to ask here to confirm... And I need to ask here to check if it will be a future issue of pg... But, sorry, I edit, refresh your question text.