# What data type to choose json or jsonb or text

Tags: json, postgresql

I would like to store a big json hash (or content, call it like you want) and by "big" I mean something above 1000 key value pairs, I don't want to do any search on that json field, I just want to retrieve it from the database and pass it to javascript to parse it and construct a visual result.

On Postgresql there is a `json` type and `jsonb` type (and maybe I can use a `text` field as well to store json) . I just want to make the right choice for that purpose, so I would like some advice from experienced people.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about actual, strict JSON (without quirks such as unquoted keys)...

`json` isn't too different from `text`. It doesn't do much apart from **validating JSON**.

`jsonb` is a different beast compared to the these two: it's a full-fledged data structure with its own internal format that has much more operations available in searches. For instance `json` has no applicable `=` (equality operator). `jsonb` has. (`text` has too, even though it's semantically different.)

It's much more sensible to index, but it has to be transformed back and forth during reads and writes.

Given that, `jsonb` doesn't look like a sound choice here.

---

... So there is only one decision left to make:

**Do you want to ensure that your database contains only valid JSON values in your column? On the database level?** Or do you trust every client of that database (server apps, typically) to only supply valid data?

**`json` is a relatively safe choice either way.** Using `text` could theoretically improve performance by a negligible margin due to absence of validation, but you'll only get specific numbers by benchmarking. But it wouln't have that safeguard against non-JSON values, and an accidental bug in the client could go unnoticed. Test responsibly!

Comment: I have a button that when a user click on it, it generate json hash via javascript and then send it via ajax to the database, I don't think a user can modify something here but even if he does it will affect his account only :)

Comment: so I think a text field is enough in this case ! :)

Comment: @medBo probably. Don't ignore the possibility of bugs in your own software though. Using `json` could safequard you from writing in wrong kinds of values for whatever reason, like sloppy quoting.

Comment: oh yeah sure, I forget that I am humain and not robot, so I will go with json. Thank you for the detailed explanation, it was very useful for me :)

Comment: Here is another useful source of information I found if someone is interested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22654170/explanation-of-jsonb-introduced-by-postgresql

Comment: [In general, most applications should prefer to store JSON data as jsonb, unless there are quite specialized needs, such as legacy assumptions about ordering of object keys.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/datatype-json.html)

Comment: Yet [`jsonb` data is stored in a decomposed binary format that makes it slightly slower to input due to added conversion overhead](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/datatype-json.html). This isn't a no-brainer choice, no.

Comment: Given the content of the answer it is not clear why _jsonb_ would not be the preferred approach.  A plus of it was mentioned: it can do equality searches. But no negatives were described.

Comment: @WestCoastProjects "has to be transformed back and forth during reads and writes" is one. But otherwise jsonb is usually a good choice, as documentation for PostgreSQL (as helpfully quoted by @Зелёный) says — for it provides more indexing flexibility, even if at the cost of losing some of JSON's obscure features like support for duplicate object keys, which are a rather rare and obscure case that rules `jsonb` out outright.

Comment: @D-side A downside of _jsonb_ that I subsequently realized is the keys of a json dict are no longer in the original order but rather alphabetical. That can disrupt human readers .

Comment: @WestCoastProjects true. I would classify that quirk into the same league as support for duplicate keys though. [RFC 7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159.html#section-4) makes a valid point that relying on the order of fields in JSON objects hurs interoperability. `jsonb` showcases exactly that 