# Efficient storage of Json in Django with postgres

Tags: json, django, postgresql

I need to store json files with models in my django app and I'm wondering whether JSONField is my best choice or not. All I need is to store it for later,  no searching or other querying is needed other than when I eventually need to retrieve it again. I'm using postgresql if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to notice that the Django `JSONField` is a PostgreSQL specific model field. Internally it uses a [`jsonb` field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/).

The [documentation of PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/datatype-json.html) says in regard to `jsonb` fields:

> jsonb data is stored in a decomposed binary format that makes it
>   slightly slower to input due to added conversion overhead, but
>   significantly faster to process

It also enforces that you put in valid JSON.

If read/write performance is the only thing that matters to you, I would go with a normal text field. If you want to enforce that JSON is put into the field and be open for future requirements (e.g. if you want to filter this column for a certain JSON key), then you are better off using `JSONField`.

Also have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39042512/5537876).

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into if text field suits my needs better. I think that my main requirement is using minimum storage but I wasn't clear about that in my question. I should probably look at using a text field together with some compression lib right?