# How to make an empty JSON object not unique in Postgres?

Tags: json, postgresql, unique-constraint

I am trying to set a unique constraint on a column that can have an empty JSON object `{}`. I am using Postgres 9.6.3.

The problem is that Postgres is treating them as unique because I can insert multiple rows with that same value. I think it is related to how Postgres treats null values as unique. How can I circumvent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a normal unique index treating the json as text.  Here is a complete example showing how it works (Corrected):

Create the table:
`create table tmp (payload json, name text);`

Create our index:
`create unique index testindex on tmp ((payload::text), name);`

Insert some rows.  The first four will work, the rest will fail.

```
insert into tmp (payload, name) values ('{}', 'foo');
// Succeeds
insert into tmp (payload, name) values ('{}', 'bar');
// Succeeds
insert into tmp (payload, name) values ('{"a":"b"}'::json, 'foo');
// Succeeds
insert into tmp (payload, name) values ('{"a":"b"}'::json, 'bar');
// Succeeds
insert into tmp (payload, name) values ('{"a":"b"}'::json, 'foo');
// Fails due to index
insert into tmp (payload, name) values ('{}', 'bar');
// Fails due to index
```

If something here isn't working as you expect, please clarify.

Comment: This does not work, more specifically, I'm setting it up to be unique in a combination of two columns: `create unique INDEX actions_constraint on actions (((payload#>>'{message, payload, content}')::text), name) where payload != '{}';` My two column names are `payload` and `name`,

Comment: Are they both actual text fields?  If so then it should work just fine, it does for me in a simple temp/test table.

Comment: `payload` is type `json` and `name` is type `text`. But yeah `payload->message->payload->>content` will be type `text`. But, we need to handle the case of a creation of a row like: `name: sometext` and payload: '{}'`.

Comment: So you're saying when name is set you *do* want `{}` to be treated as unique, e.g. not allowing the same name to be used twice?  If that's the case, just make a separate unique index on the name field alone.

Comment: Updated answer with complete example.

Comment: I only want unique combinations of `name` and `payload`. So, I should not be allowed to create two rows of `name: somename, payload: {}`. So I DON'T want every `{}` to be treated as unique. Currently your code allows me to create these duplicates, which I don't want. Thanks for your answer though,  I like how your query is in one line.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding.  In that case, all you have to do is delete the WHERE clause from the index.  `create unique index testindex on tmp ((payload::text), name)` will do it.

Comment: Thanks, your solution ended up being the most appropriate for me right now :)

Answer (score 3):

Use the `jsonb` type, a unique constraint works as expected:

```
create table my_table(
    id serial primary key, 
    jdata jsonb unique
);

insert into my_table (jdata) 
values
    ('{}'),
    ('{}');

ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "my_table_jdata_key"
```

Comment: Thanks, this works as well. However, this requires changing the data type so it looks like it takes slightly more work to migrate and seed the data. So given that I can only choose one answer I marked the @cske answer as correct. I'm also a little scared of changing the data type right now in case I break the rest of the code base.

Comment: I understand your concerns about changing data types, though it is quite simple and rather safe. The use of jsonb is particularly desirable in case you need an index on the column. See also [Explanation of JSONB introduced by PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22910602/1995738) and [When to use unstructured datatypes in Postgres](https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2016/07/14/choosing-nosql-hstore-json-jsonb/).

Answer (score 1):

You need an another partial index on name when json expression is null

```
CREATE TABLE action (
  id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
  name text,
  payload json
);

create unique INDEX actions_constraint on action (((payload#>>'{message, payload, content}')::text), name);

insert into action(name,payload) values ('a','{}');--works
insert into action(name,payload) values ('a','{}');--works

create unique INDEX actions_constraint_on_empty on action (name) where (payload::text = '{}');
--fails
truncate action;

create unique INDEX actions_constraint_on_empty on action (name) where (payload::text = '{}');
--works

insert into action(name,payload) values ('a','{}');
--works
insert into action(name,payload) values ('a','{}');
--fails
```

Check https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9759/postgresql-multi-column-unique-constraint-and-null-values

Comment: Thanks, this looks like a great answer. I want to be more explicit though to say when `payload` is equal to `{}`. How is that constructed? This isn't accepted: `create unique INDEX actions_constraint_on_empty on actions (name) where payload == '{}';`. I'm guessing I need some operator on `payload` so it is treated as JSON?

Comment: wait, it may be because I'm missing parenthesis around `payload`.

Comment: `==` ?? use `=`

Comment: Thanks, I got thrown off with `!=` so thinking the negation of that would be `==`. Right now `create unique INDEX actions_constraint_on_empty on actions (name) where (payload) = '{}';` gives me this strange error: `FATAL:  could not open relation mapping file "global/pg_filenode.map": No such file or directory`

Comment: Actually I'm no longer getting the error above but instead `operator does not exist: json = unknown`

Comment: `payload  = '{}'::json`

Comment: I tried that and it gave me an error of `error: operator does not exist: json = json`

Comment: `create unique INDEX actions_constraint_on_empty on action (name) where (payload::text = '{}') ;`

Comment: Comparing texts there work. Thanks! Can you change your solution to reflect that so I can mark it as the answer?