# "could not identify an equality operator for type json" when using distinct

Tags: postgresql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
  distinct(date(survey_results.created_at)), 
  json_build_object(
    'high', 
    ROUND( 
      COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE ( scores#>>'{medic,categories,motivation}' in('high', 'medium'))) OVER(order by date(survey_results.created_at) ) * 1.0 / 
      (
        CASE (COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE (scores#>>'{medic,categories,motivation}' in('high','medium','low'))) OVER(order by date(survey_results.created_at))) 
        WHEN 0.0 THEN 1.0 
        ELSE (COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE (scores#>>'{medic,categories,motivation}' in('high','medium','low'))) OVER(order by date(survey_results.created_at))) 
        END)* 100, 2 ) ) AS childcare FROM survey_results GROUP BY date, scores ORDER BY date asc;
```

The problem is with using `distinct(date(survey_results.created_at))`. With that in place query returns error:

```
could not identify an equality operator for type json
```

[Here is db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vUBjUyKDUNLWzySHKCKcXA/1) that show that problem. How can I fix that?

Comment: `distinct` is **NOT** a function. It always applies to **all** columns of the result. `distinct(a),b` is the same as `distinct a, (b)` or `distinct a, b`. And because of that, `distinct` tries to compare identical values of your second column which is of type `json` and can't be compared with `=`

Comment: Got it, this query returns a duplicated dates, how can I fix it without using distinct?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Use `jsonb_build_object`. Notice the `b` for binary after `json`.

Comment: `to_jsonb ` helped me. The important thing is the fact that the jsonb type does have an equality operator.

Comment: I was trying to make a UNION with JSON and was getting this message. I switched from JSON to JSONB and it worked fine. Thanks.

Comment: I discovered a similar error trying to union `json_build_array()` with another `json_build_array()` and finding it wouldn't work, then I found a similar solution switching to jsonb functions or casting to jsonb. I'm curious why there was no operator.

Comment: I understand now after running this query. It's questionable what it means to be equal for json. `SELECT LENGTH('{"a":1,"a":2}'::json::text), LENGTH('{"a":1,"a":2}'::jsonb::text), LENGTH('{   "a":1}'::json::text), LENGTH('{   "a":1}'::jsonb::text)`
A similar comparison is shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33731703/5078765

Answer (score 21):

> The problem is with using `distinct(date(survey_results.created_at))`

No. The problem is with using `DISTINCT` in that it is **not** a function. It always applies [to all columns of the result](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-select-lists.html#QUERIES-DISTINCT). `distinct(a), b` is the same as `distinct a, (b)` or `distinct a, b`. And because of that, distinct tries to compare identical values of your second column which is of type json and can't be compared with `=`

If you just want the "latest" value, you can do this with Postgres' [`distinct on ()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) operator:

```
SELECT distinct on (date(survey_results.created_at)) 
       date(survey_results.created_at) as date,
       json_build_object('high', 
        ROUND( 
      COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE ( scores#>>'{medic,categories,motivation}' in('high', 'medium'))) OVER(order by date(survey_results.created_at) ) * 1.0 / 
      (
        CASE (COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE (scores#>>'{medic,categories,motivation}' in('high','medium','low'))) OVER(order by date(survey_results.created_at))) 
        WHEN 0.0 THEN 1.0 
        ELSE (COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE (scores#>>'{medic,categories,motivation}' in('high','medium','low'))) OVER(order by date(survey_results.created_at))) 
        END)* 100, 2 ) ) AS childcare 
FROM survey_results 
GROUP BY date, scores 
ORDER BY date asc;
```

The `distinct on ()` combined with `order by` picks the first row for subsequent identical values of the column(s) specified in the `ON ()` part. In this case it would return the earliest date. If you want the "latest" row, change the sort order to `desc`

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vUBjUyKDUNLWzySHKCKcXA/1

Comment: Can we not do group by date(suryve_results.created_at)? @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 6):

Migrate to using JSONB and you won't have this issue.

This is the standard piece of advice followed a few years ago when Postgres 9.4 was coming out. Here is a thread in the Ruby on Rails community that describes migrating to JSONB as the solution.

Here is the thread: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/17706

Answer (score 2):

Facing a similar issue while working on the below SQL, we could able to fix it by explicitly casting JSON extracted column to text. as below

```
select 
b.booking_id as booking_id, 
(p.product_meta_data::json->'confirmation_window')::text as confirmation_window, 
bi.product_id as product_id 
from bookings b 
left join booking_items bi on b.booking_id = bi.booking_id 
left join products p on p.product_id = bi.product_id
```