# Check availability of object with bookings in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I want check the availability of my Offer with her bookings,

I tried with this scope:

My model:

```
scope :booking_available, -> (arrival_date, departure_date) {
 joins(:bookings).where.not('bookings.arrival_date <= ? AND bookings.departure_date >= ? AND bookings.status != ?', arrival_date, departure_date, 0)
}
```

But i got all offers in my search result duplicate by the number of bookings checked,

I tried to add `.distinct` at the end of the scope but when i use other search params i got error `PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR: could not identify an equality operator for type json` similar to [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48420438/postgresql-could-not-identify-an-equality-operator-for-type-json)

I would like know how my availability param can work with other search params ?

My controller:

```
if offer_params[:arrival_date].present? && offer_params[:departure_date].present?
  @offers = @offers.booking_available(offer_params[:arrival_date], offer_params[:departure_date])
end

@offers = @offers
      .page(params[:page])
      .per(60)

respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render template: 'offers/v2/search', status: :ok }
end
```

How i render offers in my view:

```
json[:offers] = @offers.map do |offer|

end
```

Comment: not very clear what your real question is. is it `how my availability param can work with other search params ?` or `I tried to add .distinct at the end of the scope but when i use other search params i got error`?

Comment: My question is `how my availability param can work with other search params ?`

Comment: can you show the example of what search params did you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the problem is your `joins` returning duplicate records. In Rails, `joins` returns a separate instance of the model for each matching pair of records in the association.

On your scope, instead of `joins(:bookings)`, try using `includes(:bookings).references(:bookings)`. This prevents the query from returning duplicate records.