# What is the best way to transfer the nested JSON data of a HTTP response into a SQL database?

Tags: node.js, json, postgresql, http, fastify

I am creating an API with Node.js, Fastify and Postgresql, this is supposed to get the data of a form from a yet to be developed React client, I imagine the structure of the data that will eventually arrive in my API as follows:

```
{
"quote": {
"body": "Of our qualities, none can be ascribed to the divine being without tainting it with its imperfection.",
"author": "michel de montaigne",
"page": "55",
"book": {
"title": "Diary of the Journey to Italy",
"publisher": "Eichborn Verlag",
"year": "2009"
        }
    },
"hashtag": "#God",
"user": {
"name": "betonhead",
"email": "bier@wurst.de"
    }
}
```

Now I want to store these values in my Postgresql database, for this I need to split the data to the different tables (authors, quotes, books, user, etc.) that are related to each other.

In my research on how to implement the JSON data I want to use as input to my API file I found two concepts:

```
1. creating a view in Postgres, splitting the data via Node.js middleware.

2. store the raw JSON files directly in Postgres and from there distribute them to the tables using a function.
```

My question now is which method is preferable here, or maybe there are other better methods?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

"The best way" depends on the specific constraints/requirements of your particular scenario. However, given that; a) PostgreSQL is used to store "normalized[1]" data, b) the data represented in your JSON payload relates to multiple entities, c) you don't anticipate the shape/structure of the data changing often, and d) the current API call can adequately incur the overhead of deserializing the JSON into appropriate intermediate objects/entities in order to persist them, then I'd advise on performing this work in the application layer — saving the entities accordingly in their normalized representations. However, if lower latency is more desirable, than it is to avoid eventual consistency[2] issues, you could opt for an approach that dumps the payload to some intermediately durable store (like a Message Queue) for future processing into PostgreSQL.

Another alternative would be to use a Document Database like MongoDB.

**NB**: `jsonb`[3] could be an option if you expect the payload to change frequently, and/or the shape of specific fields is dynamic/indeterminate. `jsonb` indexes and stores data in binary format, with associated metadata along with *every* record. *Don't think this would be the best approach for this scenario, but it's worth mentioning.*

**More Reading:**

1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization
2. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eventual_consistency
3. [Explanation of JSONB introduced by PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22654170/explanation-of-jsonb-introduced-by-postgresql)
4. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem