# PostgreSQL: Does jsonb sort Objects in array?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Example: `[{3},{1},{2}]`. Does it sort it? `[{1},{2}, {3}]`

I was confused because of this answer?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49833552/15502607

> 3. JSON maintains the order in which elements are inserted, while JSONB maintains the "sorted" order.

Comment: `[{3},{1},{2}]` is an invalid JSON value to begin with.

Comment: example........

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the point in the answer was about the order of the *keys* in a JSONB *object*. JSONB *arrays* maintain the order of their *elements* in the insertion order.