# How can I find all objects as objects in the list in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have one model like this:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    data = models.JSONField(null=False)
```

*SomeModel's* data is like

```
id:1, data:{'one': ['1', '2', '3'], 'two': ['2', '3'], ...}

id:2, data:{'one': ['1', '2'], 'two': ['2'], ...}

id:3, data:{'one': ['1', '3'], 'two': ['3'], ...}
```

I want to filter all objects, but I got '2'. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [JSONB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22654170/explanation-of-jsonb-introduced-by-postgresql) query ([read Django document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/#querying-jsonfield))

```
result = SomeModel.objects.filter(data__one__contains='2', data__two__contains='2')[:]
```

Always try to store data in such a way that it is less expensive to retrieve it from the database. Of course, this is not always recommended. Maybe writing is more important than reading in some cases.

If you don't know how many keys are inside the data and you want to check all of them, you have chosen a bad method!
It is better to save the data in another way.

Comment: thank you!
I thought so, too. So I changed the data and saved it!
Your answer was very helpful for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this if you change your JSON data to a dictionary:

```py
data = {
    'one': ['1', '2', '3'],
    'two': ['2', '3'],
    'three': ['1', '3']}
    # You'll probably want to loop through all your different id's

for k, v in data.items():
    if '2' in v:
        # Do something
        # Maybe make an empty dict or list above
        # and add your key and value (or the entire object) to it.
        print('Yes')
    else:
        # Do something else
        print('no')
```

Some helpful links:

- *[Check if value is in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571635/fastest-way-to-check-if-a-value-exists-in-a-list)*
- *[Iterating over dictionaries in using for loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops)*

Comment: thank ur answer :) but i need to use Django ORM's filtering option...