# Postgres JSON Query within list

Tags: json, postgresql

I have the following data in a matches table:

```
{"Id":1,"Teams":[{"Name":"TeamA","Players":[{"Name":"AAA"},{"Name":"BBB"}]},{"Name":"TeamB","Players":[{"Name":"CCC"},{"Name":"DDD"}]}],"TeamRank":[1,2]}

{"Id":2,"Teams":[{"Name":"TeamA","Players":[{"Name":"CCC"},{"Name":"BBB"}]},{"Name":"TeamB","Players":[{"Name":"AAA"},{"Name":"DDD"}]}],"TeamRank":[1,2]}
```

Ultimately I want to get a list of unique team names.

Following [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18833970/querying-inside-postgres-json-arrays) I have been trying to access the Team Name property using the following:

```
SELECT json_array_elements(match->>'Teams') FROM matches
```

This returns

```
ERROR: function json_array_elements(text) does not exist
SQL state: 42883
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
Character: 1560
```

I have also tried json_array_elements(match->>'Teams'::json) and json_array_elements(to_json(match->>'Teams')) to no avail.

But the following query

```
SELECT match->>'Teams' FROM matches;
```

Returns

```
"[{"Name":"TeamA","Players":[{"Name":"AAA"},{"Name":"BBB"}]},{"Name":"TeamB","Players":[{"Name":"CCC"},{"Name":"DDD"}]}]"
"[{"Name":"TeamA","Players":[{"Name":"CCC"},{"Name":"BBB"}]},{"Name":"TeamB","Players":[{"Name":"AAA"},{"Name":"DDD"}]}]"
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `->>` operator gives you the result as `text`, but you want it to remain `json`. Use `->` which gives you the `json` value.

Ref: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html

I believe the order of operations on `json_array_elements(match->>'Teams'::json)` converts `Teams` to `json` before it runs `->>`. `json_array_elements((match->>'Teams')::json)` should work, but is just a roundabout version of `->`.

`to_json(match->>'Teams')` converts to `text` and then gives you that text as a `json` object. It doesn't parse the `text` back into `json`.

Comment: Wow, such an easy fix. Is there any reason to use the text version? (->> over ->)

Comment: Sometimes you want text, sometimes you want more JSON, totally depends on your use case. There's a little bit of different behavior when `NULL` is involved - here's a [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4ba26/3).