# Query for element of array in JSON column

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, postgresql-9.3, lateral

Recently upgraded to using PostgreSQL 9.3.1 to leverage the JSONfunctionalities. In my table I have a json type column that has a structure like this:

```
{
   "id": "123",
   "name": "foo",
   "emails":[
      {
        "id": "123",
        "address": "somethinghere"
      },
      {
        "id": "456",
        "address": "soemthing"
      }
   ]
}
```

This is just dummy data for the purpose of the question.

Is it possible to query for a specific item in the emails array based on the id?
Pretty much: "return email where id=123)"?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

For **Postgres 9.4+** see adamc's later answer. Or:

- [Query for array elements inside JSON type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22736742/query-for-array-elements-inside-json-type/22737710#22737710)

#### Original answer for Postgres 9.3

Yes, that's possible:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl t, json_array_elements(t.json_col->'emails') AS elem
WHERE  elem->>'id' = 123;
```

`tbl` being your table name, `json_col` the name of the JSON column.

See also:

- [How do I query using fields inside the new PostgreSQL JSON datatype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10560394/how-do-i-query-using-fields-inside-the-new-postgresql-json-datatype/10560761#10560761)

About the implicit `CROSS JOIN LATERAL`:

- [PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number/8767450#8767450)

Index to support this kind of query:

- [Index for finding an element in a JSON array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404055/index-for-finding-element-in-json-array/18405706#18405706)

Comment: This is the best answer I have seen for this type of question so far.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Sorry for off-top, but could you please help with this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49532773 (Thanks in advance!)

Answer (score 10):

With a JSONB column in Postgres 9.4+ you can use the contains operator `@>` to query for an element in an array:

```
SELECT * FROM jsontest WHERE data @> '{ "emails": [{ "id": "123" }] }';
```

See [Query for array elements inside JSON type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22737710/740997) for more details.

Here is a working example:

```
CREATE TABLE jsontest(data JSONB NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO jsontest VALUES (
  '{
     "name": "foo",
     "id": "123",
     "emails": 
     [
       {
         "address": "somethinghere",
         "id": "123"
       },
       {
         "address": "soemthing",
         "id": "456"
       }
     ]
  }'
);
SELECT * FROM jsontest WHERE data @> '{ "emails": [{ "id": "123" }] }';

data
----
{"id": "123", "name": "foo", "emails": [{"id": "123", "address": "somethinghere"}, {"id": "456", "address": "soemthing"}]}
```

(1 row)

Comment: how to delete address by id 123 ?

Comment: `delete FROM jsontest WHERE data @> '{ "emails": [{ "id": "123" }] }';`

Answer (score 3):

Came across this post and found that you can directly query on table like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table_name, json_array_elements(json_column) AS data
WHERE  data->>'id' = 123;
```

Omitting this part:

```
json_array_elements(t.json_col->'emails')
```

Comment: this is super super useful I have been struggling with CTE to try and make it work, and this just solves my need beautifully. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can do it as simple as :

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE emails->>'id' = '123';
```

it seems you store the id as string, if it was an integer you can do it like this :

```
SELECT *  from table WHERE cast(emails->>'id' as integer ) = 123  ;
```

or you can get all the rows with id > 10

```
SELECT *  from table WHERE cast(emails->>'id' as integer ) > 10  ;
```

Comment: I've tried this on Postgres 9.4.4 and it doesn't work: