# How to query and index JSON data nested multiple levels deep in PostgreSQL 9.3+?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

In PostgreSQL 9.3, I am storing some fairly complex JSON objects with arrays nested within arrays.  This snippet isn't the real data, but illustrates the same concept:

```
{
   "customerId" : "12345",
   "orders" : [{
      "orderId" : "54321",
      "lineItems" : [{
         "productId" : "abc",
         "qty" : 3
      }, {
         "productId" : "def",
         "qty" : 1
      }]
   }
}
```

I want the ability for SQL queries to operate on `lineItem` objects... not just within this single JSON structure, but across all JSON objects in that table column.  For instance, a SQL query that returns all distinct `productId`'s, and their total sold `qty` sums.  To prevent such a query from taking all day, I would probably want an index on `lineItem` or its child fields.

Using [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19568123/query-for-element-of-array-in-json-column), I figured out how to write a query that works:

```
SELECT
   line_item->>'productId' AS product_id, 
   SUM(CAST(line_item->>'qty' AS INTEGER)) AS qty_sold
FROM
   my_table, 
   json_array_elements(my_table.my_json_column->'orders') AS order,
   json_array_elements(order->'lineItems') AS line_item
GROUP BY product_id;
```

However, that original StackOverflow question dealt with data that was only nested **one level** deep rather than two.  I extended the same concept (i.e. a "lateral join" within the `FROM` clause) by adding an extra lateral join to dive one level deeper.  However, I'm not sure if this is the best approach, so the first part of my question is:  What's the best approach for querying JSON data that is **an arbitrary number of levels** deep in the JSON objects?

For the second part of this, creating an index on such nested data, [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404055/index-for-finding-an-element-in-a-json-array/18405706#18405706) again deals with data nested only one level deep.  However, I'm just completely lost, with my head swimming trying to think of how I would apply this to a deeper number of levels.  Can anyone please offer a clear approach for indexing data that is at least two levels deep, as with `lineItems` above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To deal with the infinite recursion issue, you need to use a [recursive CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-with.html) to operate upon each individual json element in each table row:

```
WITH RECURSIVE

raw_json as (

  SELECT 

    *

  FROM

  (VALUES 

  (1,
  '{
  "customerId": "12345",
  "orders": [
    {
      "orderId": "54321",
      "lineItems": [
        {
          "productId": "abc",
          "qty": 3
        },
        {
          "productId": "def",
          "qty": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}'::json),

  (2,
  '{
  "customerId": "678910",
  "artibitraryLevel": {
    "orders": [
      {
        "orderId": "55345",
        "lineItems": [
          {
            "productId": "abc",
            "qty": 3
          },
          {
            "productId": "ghi",
            "qty": 10
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}'::json)



) a(id,sample_json)

),


json_recursive as (

  SELECT
    a.id,
    b.k,
    b.v,
    b.json_type,
    case when b.json_type = 'object' and not (b.v->>'customerId') is null then b.v->>'customerId' else a.customer_id end customer_id, --track any arbitrary id when iterating through json graph
    case when b.json_type = 'object' and not (b.v->>'orderId') is null then b.v->>'orderId' else a.order_id end order_id,
    case when b.json_type = 'object' and not (b.v->>'productId') is null then b.v->>'productId' else a.product_id end product_id

  FROM

    (

      SELECT

        id,
        sample_json v,
        case left(sample_json::text,1)
          when '[' then 'array'
          when '{' then 'object'
          else 'scalar'
        end json_type, --because choice of json accessor function depends on this, and for some reason postgres has no built in function to get this value
        sample_json->>'customerId' customer_id,
        sample_json->>'orderId' order_id,
        sample_json->>'productId' product_id

      FROM

        raw_json
    ) a
    CROSS JOIN LATERAL (

      SELECT

        b.k,
        b.v,
        case left(b.v::text,1)
          when '[' then 'array'
          when '{' then 'object'
          else 'scalar'
        end json_type


      FROM

        json_each(case json_type when 'object' then a.v else null end ) b(k,v) --get key value pairs for individual elements if we are dealing with standard object

     UNION ALL


      SELECT

        null::text k,
        c.v,
        case left(c.v::text,1)
          when '[' then 'array'
          when '{' then 'object'
          else 'scalar'
        end json_type


      FROM

        json_array_elements(case json_type when 'array' then a.v else null end) c(v) --if we have an array, just get the elements and use parent key


    ) b


UNION ALL --recursive term

    SELECT
    a.id,
    b.k,
    b.v,
    b.json_type,
    case when b.json_type = 'object' and not (b.v->>'customerId') is null then b.v->>'customerId' else a.customer_id end customer_id,
    case when b.json_type = 'object' and not (b.v->>'orderId') is null then b.v->>'orderId' else a.order_id end order_id,
    case when b.json_type = 'object' and not (b.v->>'productId') is null then b.v->>'productId' else a.product_id end product_id




  FROM

    json_recursive a
    CROSS JOIN LATERAL (

      SELECT

        b.k,
        b.v,
        case left(b.v::text,1)
          when '[' then 'array'
          when '{' then 'object'
          else 'scalar'
        end json_type


      FROM

        json_each(case json_type when 'object' then a.v else null end ) b(k,v)


     UNION ALL


      SELECT

        a.k,
        c.v,
        case left(c.v::text,1)
          when '[' then 'array'
          when '{' then 'object'
          else 'scalar'
        end json_type


      FROM

        json_array_elements(case json_type when 'array' then a.v else null end) c(v)

    ) b

)
```

Then you can either sum "qty" by an arbitrary id...

```
SELECT
  customer_id,
  sum(v::text::integer)

FROM

  json_recursive

WHERE

  k = 'qty'

GROUP BY 

  customer_id
```

Or you can get the "lineItem" objects and manipulate them as you desire:

```
SELECT 

  *

FROM 

  json_recursive 

WHERE

  k = 'lineItems' and json_type = 'object'
```

As for the indexing, you could adapt the recursive query into a function that returns the unique keys for each json object in each row of your original table and then it to create a functional index on your json column:

```
SELECT

  array_agg(DISTINCT k)

FROM

  json_recursive

WHERE

  not k is null
```