# Existance in JSON field check query

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, exists

I'm using **PostgreSQL JSON** type field in my database.

JSON format:

```
[
   {"id": "13", "something": "not_important"},
   {"id": "5426565165191919", "something": "not_important"},
   {"id": "46", "something": "not_important"}
   ...
]
```

List of IDs like `["13", "46", "84"]`.

How to make query that tell me that some ID is not exists? (Not important which one.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH t(data) AS (
   VALUES ('           [
   {"id": "13", "something": "not_important"},
   {"id": "5426565165191919", "something": "not_important"},
   {"id": "46", "something": "not_important"}
   ]'::json)
   )
SELECT NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT data::text, o::text  -- cast to text for display in fiddle
   FROM   t, json_array_elements(t.data) AS d(o)
   RIGHT  JOIN unnest('{13,46,84}'::bigint[]) u(id) ON u.id = (d.o->>'id')::bigint
   WHERE  d.o IS NULL
   ) AS all_found;
```

- The CTE (`WITH` query) just substitutes for an actual table `t`.
- Using `LEFT JOIN / NOT NULL` to identify missing values. Details:

  - [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694)
- Assuming that `bigint` is wide enough to hold your `id` values. Else, switch to `numeric`.

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/4510)

More explanation in this related answer:

- [Query for array elements inside JSON type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22736742/query-for-array-elements-inside-json-type/22737710#22737710)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by left-joining your "expected" ids against the "actual" ids, and then filtering for rows in the result-set where the "actual" ids table failed to join. The only trick is extracting from the JSON the integral id values. This is how it could be done, assuming you are hard-coding *all* ids right in the SQL:

```
select
    expected.id
from
    (select substring(value::varchar from 2 for char_length(value::varchar)-2)::bigint id from json_array_elements('["13","46","84"]'::json)) expected
    left join (select (value->>'id')::bigint id from json_array_elements('[{"id":"13"},{"id":"5426565165191919"},{"id":"46"}]'::json)) actual on actual.id=expected.id
where
    actual.id is null
;
```

In the above query, I'm calling `json_array_elements()` to extract the individual array elements from each JSON string. Because the target JSON string has object array elements, we must further extract the `"id"` values, which can be done with the `->` operator. Note that `value` seems to be the default name assigned to the single column output by the `json_array_elements()` function.

A quirk is that the extracted JSON (i.e. the `value` value) is still of type `json`, and it seems you can't cast `json` text directly to an integral value such as `int` or `bigint`, even if the entire `json` text consists only of a valid `int`/`bigint`, but you can go through `varchar` to get there:

```
select '34'::json::bigint; -- "ERROR:  cannot cast type json to bigint"
select '34'::json::varchar::bigint; -- works, 34
```

That's why I had to cast the `json` values with `::varchar::bigint`.

Also, I had to extract the expected ids from their double-quoted strings using `substring()`, as the `::bigint` cast would otherwise not work.

Also, minor point, I used `bigint` and not `int` because you've got a rather large number there (5426565165191919).

If you want to just select a boolean value indicating if at least one expected id is missing, you can change the select clause to read:

```
select
    case when count(expected.id)>0 then true else false end some_missing
```

Comment: You can avoid the additional cast by using [`->>`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-json.html) (which returns `text`) instead of `->`.

Comment: Ah, good point. Is there any way to avoid the additional cast in the expected ids subquery? There's no dereference there, it's just `value::varchar`, so you can't use `->>`.

Comment: You could use another instance of  `json_array_elements()` as long as you provide the input as JSON array. I used a plain array (`bigint[]`) with the appropriate `unnest()` in my answer.