# Search and select from Postgres NOSQL / json data

Tags: json, postgresql

Can anyone help me to search inside json datatype of Postgres database.

I have one table say `transactions` and contains following like values array:

`column: "data" datatype: json`

Single demo transaction:

```
{
    "id": "tran_54645bcb98ba7acfe204",
    "amount": 4200,
    ...
    "fees": [
        {
            "type": "application",
            "application": "app_1d70acbf80c8c35ce83680715c06be0d15c06be0d",
            "payment": "pay_917018675b21ca03c4fb",
            "amount": 420,
            "currency": "EUR",
            "billed_at": null
        }
    ]
}
```

Nested transaction list:

```
[
    {
        "id": "tran_54645bcb98ba7acfe204",
        "amount": 4200,
        "fees": [
            {
                "type": "application",
                "application": "app_1d70acbf80c8c35ce83680715c06be0d15c06be0d",
                "payment": "pay_917018675b21ca03c4fb",
                "amount": 420,
                "currency": "EUR",
                "billed_at": null
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "tran_98645bcb98ba7acfe204",
        "amount": 4200,
        "fees": [
            {
                "type": "application",
                "application": "app_1d70acbf80c8c35ce83680715c06be0d15c06be0d",
                "payment": "pay_917018675b21ca03c4fb",
                "amount": 120,
                "currency": "AUD",
                "billed_at": null
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

If I want to get all the transactions having `amount > 300` AND also with `currency = EUR` how I can get them?
I am new to Postgres so need help in understanding query building for Postgres nosql specially with PHP

Comment: Postgres version? Table definition? Also, there is no such thing as "postgre". [The short name of PostgreSQL is Postgres.](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Identity_Guidelines) Please fix.

Comment: I have version 9.4
You can consider table definition as follow:
`table name: transaction
columns: data`

Comment: So you are using `json`, not `jsonb`? The latter [might be a good idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10560394/how-do-i-query-using-fields-inside-the-new-postgresql-json-datatype/10560761#10560761).

Comment: In your example, there is a single item in the nested JSON array. Is that always the case?

Comment: No, it wont be always it will be a large data and multiple array. it is a just a single demo transaction i have shown

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For just a *single* element in the nested JSON array:

```
SELECT *
FROM   transactions
WHERE (data #>> '{fees,0,amount}')::numeric > '300'
AND   (data #>> '{fees,0,currency}') = 'EUR';
```

For arrays with more elements you need to do more.
The manual about [JSON Functions and Operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-json.html).

Since you are using Postgres 9.4: With `jsonb` there would be superior options, in particular for multiple array elements:

- [Query for array elements inside JSON type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22736742/query-for-array-elements-inside-json-type/22737710#22737710)
- [Index for finding an element in a JSON array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404055/index-for-finding-an-element-in-a-json-array/18405706#18405706)

To get the sum you are asking for in the comment:

```
SELECT sum((data #>> '{fees,0,amount}')::numeric) AS sum_amount
FROM   ...
```

Comment: One more question can i get aggregate SUM(amount) for all amount > 300 as per above query