# Use jsonb array as table

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, indexing, jsonb

In a Postgres 9.4 database, I have a json array with around 1000 elements of the structure:
`"oid: aaa, instance:bbb, value:ccc"`

Sample:

```json
{"_id": 37637070
, "data": [{"oid": "11.5.15.1.4", "value": "1", "instance": "1.1.4"}
         , {"oid": "11.5.15.1.9", "value": "17", "instance": "1.1.4"}
         , {"oid": "12.5.15.1.5", "value": "0.0.0.0", "instance": "0"}]}
```

`oid` and `instance` are unique per json array.  If I was given the option to change the structure I would have changed the format to *key:value*:

```json
{"11.5.15.1.4-1.1.4":"1", "11.5.15.1.9-1.1.4": "17", "12.5.15.1.5-0": "0.0.0.0"}
```

However, if I need to stay with the old structure

1. What is the fastest way to get specific `oid` from the array?
2. What is the fastest way to get a table with 3 columns of `oid`, `instance` and `value`. Or even better a pivot table with oid+instance as the column header.

For 2. I tried the following, but it was pretty slow on a large table:

```sql
select *
from (
   select a->>'oid' oid, a->>'instance' instance, a->>'value' value1, id
   from (
      select jsonb_array_elements(config#>'{data}')  a, id
      from configuration
      ) b
   ) c
where  oid = '1.3.6.1.4.1.7352.3.10.2.5.35.3' and instance = '0' and value1 <> '1';
```

Comment: Your query can be made a lot simpler looking as `select a->>'oid' oid, a->>'instance' instance, a->>'value' value1, id from (
    select jsonb_array_elements(config#>'{data}') a, id from configuration ) b
  where a->>'instance' = '1.1.4' and a->>'oid' = '11.5.15.1.4' and a->>'value'<>'2';` but PostgreSQL optimizes both your and this query into the same thing.

Comment: Though it might make it faster if in the innermost query you also restricted the resulting rows with `config@>'{"data":[{"oid":"11.5.15.1.4","instance":"0"}]}'`, then there wouldn't need to be as many rows from `jsonb_array_elements` to check.

Comment: The definition of your table should be in the question. What you get with `\d configuration` in psql. Or a valid `CREATE TABLE` script.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Query

Your table definition is missing. Assuming:

```sql
CREATE TABLE configuration (
  config_id serial PRIMARY KEY
, config jsonb NOT NULL
);
```

To find the a `value` and its row for given `oid` and `instance`:

```sql
SELECT c.config_id, d->>'value' AS value
FROM   configuration c
     , jsonb_array_elements(config->'data') d  -- default col name is "value"
WHERE  d->>'oid'      = '1.3.6.1.4.1.7352.3.10.2.5.35.3'
AND    d->>'instance' = '0'
AND    d->>'value'   <> '1';
```

That's an implicit `LATERAL` join. Compare:

- [Query for array elements inside JSON type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22736742/query-for-array-elements-inside-json-type/22737710#22737710)

> 2. What is the fastest way to get a table with 3 columns of `oid`, `instance` and `value.`

I suppose to use [**`jsonb_populate_recordset()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE), then you can provide data types in the table definition. Assuming `text` for all:

```
CREATE TYPE pg_temp.data_pattern (oid text, value text, instance text);
```

Can also be a persisted (non-temp) table or view. This one is only for the current session. Then:

```sql
SELECT c.config_id, d.*
FROM   configuration c
     , jsonb_populate_recordset(NULL::data_pattern, c.config->'data') d;
```

That's all. The first query rewritten:

```sql
SELECT c.config_id, d.*
FROM   configuration c
     , jsonb_populate_recordset(NULL::data_pattern, c.config->'data') d
WHERE  d.oid      = '1.3.6.1.4.1.7352.3.10.2.5.35.3'
AND    d.instance = '0'
AND    d.value   <> '1';
```

But that's *slower* than the first query. Key to performance with bigger table is index support:

### Index

You could easily index the normalized (translated) table or the alternative layout you proposed in the question. Indexing your **current layout** is not as obvious, but also possible. For best performance I suggest a functional index on just the `data` key with the `jsonb_path_ops` operator class. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#JSON-INDEXING)

> The technical difference between a `jsonb_ops` and a `jsonb_path_ops` GIN
> index is that the former creates independent index items for each key
> and value in the data, while the latter creates index items only for
> each value in the data.

This **should work wonders** for performance:

```
CREATE INDEX configuration_my_idx ON configuration
USING gin ((config->'data') jsonb_path_ops);
```

One might expect that only a complete match for a JSON array element would work, like:

```
SELECT * FROM configuration
WHERE  (config->'data') @> '[{"oid": "1.3.6.1.4.1.7352.3.10.2.5.35.3"
                            , "instance": "0", "value": "1234"}]';
```

Note the JSON array notation (with **enclosing `[]`**) of the provided value: that's required.

But array elements with a **subset of keys** work as well:

```
SELECT * FROM configuration
WHERE  (config->'data') @> '[{"oid": "1.3.6.1.4.1.7352.3.10.2.5.35.3"
                            , "instance": "0"}]'
```

The hard part is to incorporate your added predicate `value <> '1'`. Care must be taken to apply all predicates to the *same* array element. You could combine this with the first query:

```sql
SELECT c.*, d->>'value' AS value
FROM   configuration c
     , jsonb_array_elements(config->'data') d
WHERE  (config->'data') @> '[{"oid": "1.3.6.1.4.1.7352.3.10.2.5.35.3", "instance": "0"}]'
AND    d->>'oid'      = '1.3.6.1.4.1.7352.3.10.2.5.35.3'  -- must be repeated
AND    d->>'instance' = '0'                               -- must be repeated
AND    d->>'value'   <> '1'                               -- here we can rule out
```

Voilá.

#### Special index

If your table is huge, index size may be a deciding factor. You could compare performance of this special solution with a functional index:

This function extracts a Postgres array of *oid-instance* combinations from a given `jsonb` value:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_config_json2arr(_j jsonb)
  RETURNS text[]
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE AS
$func$
SELECT ARRAY(
   SELECT (elem->>'oid') || '-' || (elem->>'instance')
   FROM   jsonb_array_elements(_j) elem
   )
$func$;
```

We can build a functional index based on this:

```
CREATE INDEX configuration_conrfig_special_idx ON configuration
USING  gin (f_config_json2arr(config->'data'));
```

And base the query on it:

```
SELECT * FROM configuration
WHERE  f_config_json2arr(config->'data') @> '{1.3.6.1.4.1.7352.3.10.2.5.35.3-0}'::text[]
```

The idea is that the index should be substantially smaller because it only stores the combined values without keys. The [***array*** containment operator **`@>`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-OPERATORS-TABLE) itself should perform similar to the [jsonb containment operator **`@>`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE). I don't expect a big difference, but I would be very interested which is faster.

Similar to the first solution in this related answer (but more specialized):

- [Index for finding an element in a JSON array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404055/index-for-finding-an-element-in-a-json-array/18405706#18405706)

#### Asides

- I would not use `oid` as column name. It's in use for internal purposes in Postgres.
- If possible, use a plain, normalized table without JSON.

Comment: Thank you for an excellent example of the `jsonb_populate_recordset` usage. I am curious of performance benefits. Maybe OP will share the results of his tests.

Comment: For some reason the query suggested takes around 20 seconds while the following takes 5 seconds - SELECT obj->>'oid', obj->>'value'
FROM   configuration r, jsonb_array_elements(r.config->'data') obj
WHERE  obj->>'oid' = '3.10.2.5.35.3'

Comment: Thank you very much! Once I added the index the performance is very good. From several seconds it went down to less than one second. Can I have in the condition (config->'data') @> '[{"oid": "1.3.6.1.4.1.7352.3.10.2.5.35.3", "instance": "0"}]' several elements with OR between them?

Comment: @user1409708: I suggest you start a new question. You can always link to this one for context. BTW, did you just try the `jsonb_path_ops` index or the functional index as well?