# JSONB: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4, jsonb, set-returning-functions

I am (still) new to postgresql and jsonb. I am trying to select some records from a subquery and am stuck. My data column looks like this (jsonb):

```
{"people": [{"age": "50", "name": "Bob"}], "another_key": "no"}
{"people": [{"age": "73", "name": "Bob"}], "another_key": "yes"}
```

And here is my query. I want to select all names that are "Bob" whose age is greater than 30:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE (SELECT (a->>'age')::float
       FROM (SELECT jsonb_array_elements(data->'people') as a
             FROM mytable) as b 
       WHERE a @> json_object(ARRAY['name', 'Bob'])::jsonb
      ) > 30;
```

I get the error:

```
more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

I don't quite understand. If I do some simple substitution (just for testing) I can do this:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE  (50) > 30  -- 50 is the age of the youngest Bob
```

and that returns both rows.

Comment: A question like this should provide an exact table definition showing all relevant columns, data types and constraints - what you get with `\d mytable` in psql or a valid `CREATE TABLE` script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error means just what it says:

> more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

The expression in the `WHERE` clause expects a single value (just like you substituted in your added test), but your subquery returns ***multiple*** rows. `jsonb_array_elements()` is a set-returning function.

Assuming this table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
  id   serial PRIMARY KEY
, data jsonb
);
```

The JSON array for `"people"` wouldn't make sense if there couldn't be multiple persons inside. Your examples with only a single person are misleading. Some more revealing test data:

```sql
INSERT INTO mytable (data)
VALUES
  ('{"people": [{"age": "55", "name": "Bill"}], "another_key": "yes"}')
, ('{"people": [{"age": "73", "name": "Bob"}], "another_key": "yes"}')
, ('{"people": [{"age": "73", "name": "Bob"}
               ,{"age": "77", "name": "Udo"}], "another_key": "yes"}');
```

The third row has two people.

I suggest a query with a `LATERAL` join:

```sql
SELECT t.id, p.person
FROM   mytable t 
     , jsonb_array_elements(t.data->'people') p(person)  -- implicit LATERAL
WHERE (t.data->'people') @> '[{"name": "Bob"}]'
AND    p.person->>'name' = 'Bob'
AND   (p.person->>'age')::int > 30;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/pC22lLKm)

The first `WHERE` condition `WHERE (t.data->'people') @> '[{"name": "Bob"}]'` is logically redundant, but it helps performance by eliminating irrelevant rows early: don't even unnest JSON arrays without a `"Bob"` in it.

For big tables, this is ***much*** more efficient with a matching index. If you run this kind of query regularly, you should have one:

```
CREATE INDEX mytable_people_gin_idx ON mytable
USING gin ((data->'people') jsonb_path_ops);
```

Related, with more explanation:

- [Postgres 9.4 jsonb array as table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30827578/postgres-9-4-jsonb-array-as-table/30829650#30829650)
- [Index for finding an element in a JSON array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404055/index-for-finding-an-element-in-a-json-array/18405706#18405706)

In **Postgres 12** or later consider using SQL/JSON path expressions instead. See:

- [Find rows containing a key in a JSONB array of records](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/196635/3684)

Comment: That makes sense but I am lost on "The first WHERE condition WHERE  t.data @> '{"people":[{"name": "Bob"}]}'"......do you mean "WHERE (t.data->'people') @> '[{"name": "Bob"}]'"?  Which way is more efficient?

Comment: @kristen: That was an artifact. Either expression is good. The important part is to match the index. I switched the index to more narrow expression index (smaller, faster, more specialized) and forgot to update the text. Fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

In your subquery:

```
SELECT (a->>'age')::float
FROM (SELECT jsonb_array_elements(data->'people') as a
      FROM mytable) as b
WHERE a @> json_object(ARRAY['name', 'Bob'])::jsonb
```

You selected all the rows of `mytable` all over again. That's why your subquery returns multiple values.

**If you want to select rows from your table** containing an element that satisfies certain conditions, then in your conditions, don't re-select from that table; use the row you've already selected in your outer query:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE exists(SELECT 1
    FROM (SELECT jsonb_array_elements(data->'people') as person) as x
    WHERE person @> '{"name": "Bob"}'
    AND (person->>'age')::float > 30)
```

As far as I can tell, that weird double-subquery syntax is necessary. Note that `data` is from the outer query.

**If you wanted to select all the JSON objects from the `"people"` fields** that satisfy your conditions, then just aggregate all those `"people"` elements and filter them:

```
SELECT person
FROM (SELECT jsonb_array_elements(data->'people') as person
      FROM mytable) as x
WHERE person @> '{"name": "Bob"}'
AND (person->>'age')::float > 30
```

Answer (score -1):

The correct query for your example is the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable
WHERE (data  #> '{people,0}' ->>'name') = 'Bob' 
AND (data  #> '{people,0}' ->>'age')::integer > 30
```

(note that the value of "people" is an array).

Comment: I think I need the subquery b/c I don't know where in my "people" list 'Bob' will be...I think I will need to use jsonb_array_elements b/c of this.