# SELECT by json array value

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I have a table named "games" with 2 fields:

1. name (varchar)
2. data (json)

This is a sample row of data:

| name | data |
| --- | --- |
| Test | {"players":["PlayerOne","PlayerTwo"],"topPlayers":["PlayerTen","PlayerThirteen"]} |

Now I want to `SELECT` rows which have a "player" named "PlayerOne".

I've tried following SQL commands without success:

`SELECT * FROM games WHERE data -> players = 'PlayerOne';`

`SELECT * FROM games WHERE data ->> players = 'PlayerOne';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The position of the array element won't be the same every time, so the direct reference you tried doesn't work - even after fixing your expression: `data -> 'players' ->> 0` or `data #>> '{players,0}'`

Use the data type `jsonb` instead of `json`, and the [`jsonb` containment operator **`@>`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   games
WHERE  data @> '{"players":["PlayerOne"]}';
```

If you can't change the table definition, add a cast in the query:

```
...
WHERE  data::jsonb @> '{"players":["PlayerOne"]}';
```

Either way, if the table is big, you want to support this with an index - an expression index in the latter case. See:

- [What's the proper index for querying structures in arrays in Postgres jsonb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26499266/whats-the-proper-index-for-querying-structures-in-arrays-in-postgres-jsonb/27708358#27708358)
- [Postgres 9.4 jsonb array as table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30827578/postgres-9-4-jsonb-array-as-table/30829650#30829650)