# Select rows where a value is found in json array

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a table `uploads_table`:

| upload_id | value |
| --- | --- |
| A | [{"doc_name": "doc1a", "doc_type": "pdf"}, {"doc_name": "doc1b", "doc_type": "csv"}] |
| B | [{"doc_name": "doc2a", "doc_type": "csv"}, {"doc_name": "doc2b", "doc_type": "csv"}] |
| C | [{"doc_name": "doc3a", "doc_type": "pdf"}] |

What would be the Postgres query to return all the `upload_id, value` from `uploads_table` which has at least one "doc_type" as "pdf".

Expected result:

| upload_id | value |
| --- | --- |
| A | [{"doc_name": "doc1a", "doc_type": "pdf"}, {"doc_name": "doc1b", "doc_type": "csv"}] |
| C | [{"doc_name": "doc3a", "doc_type": "pdf"}] |

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`jsonb` "contains" operator **`@>`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   uploads_table
WHERE  value @> jsonb '[{"doc_type":"pdf"}]';
```

This is, of course, assuming that `value` is type `jsonb` - as it should be.

A GIN index on `(value)` will make this **fast**.
Even faster with a more specialized `jsonb_path_ops` index:

```
CREATE INDEX uploads_table_values_gin_idx ON uploads_table USING gin (value jsonb_path_ops);
```

See:

- [What's the proper index for querying structures in arrays in Postgres jsonb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26499266/whats-the-proper-index-for-querying-structures-in-arrays-in-postgres-jsonb/27708358#27708358)

Related:

- [Query for key in an element of a JSON array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73969448/query-for-key-in-an-element-of-a-json-array/74009722#74009722)
- [SELECT by json array value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74503708/select-by-json-array-value/74504773#74504773)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in function [jsonb_array_elements](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) in PostgreSQL. The query statement will be as follows:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM uploads_table
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM jsonb_array_elements(value) AS doc
    WHERE doc->>'doc_type' = 'pdf'
);
```

The result is as shown in the image below:
[image]

Comment: This will be rather slow since the database has to do a sequential scan of the entire table