# Is it safe to use jsonb_array_elements() twice in the same SELECT list?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, set-returning-functions

Is it safe to select multiple columns with [jsonb_array_elements](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) in a single `SELECT` statement? Is there a guarantee that the order of the expanded elements in one column is the same as the order in the second column?

**Example**: My table contains a column `data` that contains a json array. Each element of the array is an object with two properties (`id` and `name`):

```
                                data                                
--------------------------------------------------------------------
 [{"id": "11", "name": "entry11"}, {"id": "12", "name": "entry12"}]
 [{"id": "21", "name": "entry21"}, {"id": "22", "name": "entry22"}]
```

If I run

```sql
with my_table(data) as (values
    ('[{"id": "11", "name":"entry11"},{"id": "12", "name": "entry12"}]'::jsonb),
    ('[{"id": "21", "name":"entry21"},{"id": "22", "name": "entry22"}]'::jsonb)
)
select 
  jsonb_array_elements(data)->'id' as id,
  jsonb_array_elements(data)->'name' as name
from my_table
;
```

I get the expected result:

```
  id  |   name    
------+-----------
 "11" | "entry11"
 "12" | "entry12"
 "21" | "entry21"
 "22" | "entry22"
```

**My Question**: Is there a risk that the `name` *entry22* could end up in the row with `id` *21* as the two invocations of `jsonb_array_elements` are handled independently by the database? My experiments (also with larger tables) suggest that it always works. But as relational databases usually [don't have a stable ordering of rows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17503095/2129801) I wonder if I can rely on that result.

Comment: Is there a reason to not `select j->'id' as id, j->'name' as name from my_table, LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(data) as j;`? Then you shouldn't worry about order.

Comment: I believe it's safe, but am not certain (and would prefer the lateral table function). But good question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a guarantee. But it's a weak one.

`id` and `name` will stay in sync (come from the same nested object) because the two set-returning functions are evaluated in "lockstep". [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-FUNCTIONS-RETURNING-SET)

> If there is more than one set-returning function in the query's select
> list, the behavior is similar to what you get from putting the
> functions into a single `LATERAL ROWS FROM( ... ) FROM`-clause item.
> For each row from the underlying query, there is an output row using
> the first result from each function, then an output row using the
> second result, and so on. If some of the set-returning functions
> produce fewer outputs than others, null values are substituted for the
> missing data, so that the total number of rows emitted for one
> underlying row is the same as for the set-returning function that
> produced the most outputs. Thus the **set-returning functions run “in
> lockstep”** until they are all exhausted, and then execution continues
> with the next underlying row.

**Bold** emphasis mine.

Since both your calls are guaranteed to return the same number of rows, this even works reliably before Postgres 10 (where the behavior of multiple set-returning functions in the `SELECT` list was reformed (sanitized). See:

- [What is the expected behaviour for multiple set-returning functions in SELECT clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39863505/what-is-the-expected-behaviour-for-multiple-set-returning-functions-in-select-cl/39864815#39864815)

Unlike `json`, `jsonb` has a deterministic sort order of nested elements. But the only relevant aspect here is the order of array items, and that is always significant and preserved in `json` and `jsonb` alike.

#### Optimize query

Elaborating on what we just learned about the internal workings, your query:

```sql
SELECT jsonb_array_elements(data) -> 'id'   AS id
     , jsonb_array_elements(data) -> 'name' AS name
FROM   tbl;
```

... is equivalent to:

```sql
SELECT t.id, x.i->'id' AS id, x.n->'name' AS name
FROM   tbl t
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL ROWS FROM (jsonb_array_elements(t.data), jsonb_array_elements(t.data)) x(i, n);
```

Makes it even more obvious, that it should be simplified to a single function call in a subquery. Then fields cannot get out of sync to begin with:

```sql
SELECT t.id, x->'id' AS id, x->'name' AS name
FROM   tbl t
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(t.data) x;
```

Or, with minimal syntax:

```sql
SELECT id, x->'id' AS id, x->'name' AS name
FROM   tbl, jsonb_array_elements(data) x;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zfPSGxCj)

When returning multiple, separate fields from the same function call, move the function call to a subquery as demonstrated. Else you risk (costly) repeated evaluation. See:

- [Split function-returned record into multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38297935/split-function-returned-record-into-multiple-columns/38297985#38297985)
- [How to avoid multiple function evals with the (func()).* syntax in a query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18369778/how-to-avoid-multiple-function-evals-with-the-func-syntax-in-a-query/18370271#18370271)

#### True issue with (multiple) SRF in the `SELECT` list

All of the above harbor a **trap**. If a SRF in the `SELECT` list does not return a row (like when `jsonb_array_elements()` finds an empty array), the row is removed from the result. When there are multiple SRF in the `SELECT` list, the row is removed when all of them come up empty. This can lead to surprising results. From my experience, few are aware of the subtle implications.

If that side effect is intended, it's much clearer spelled out as `CROSS JOIN` as demonstrated above.

If that side effect is not intended, and you'd rather preserve all rows, use `LEFT JOIN LATERAL ... ON true` instead:

```
SELECT t.id, x->'id' AS id, x->'name' AS name
FROM   tbl t
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(t.data) x ON true;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zfPSGxCj)

**Use this query**, unless you know better. See:

- [What is the difference between a LATERAL JOIN and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-a-lateral-join-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

#### Aside: `jsonb_populate_recordset()` for this particular query

There is a more efficient way for your particular query with `jsonb_populate_recordset()`: faster, and with implicit type casts.

Create a fitting composite type once if you don't have one:

```
CREATE TYPE my_rowtype AS (id int, name text);
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT t.id, x.id, x.name
FROM   tbl t
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL jsonb_populate_recordset(null::my_rowtype, t.data) x ON true
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/HvH5NPrC)

Related:

- [Use jsonb array as table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30827578/use-jsonb-array-as-table/30829650#30829650)
- [jsonb query with nested objects in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29108179/jsonb-query-with-nested-objects-in-an-array/29114520#29114520)