# Rails way to query on array inside JSON data type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, json, postgresql

I have a column in my table with JSON data type where I am storing an array.

**Migration**

```
class AddEditSummaryToPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :posts, :edit_summary, :json
  end
end
```

**Post**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :edit_summary, JSON
end
```

This is how the data is stored:

```
:id => 2,
:edit_summary => [
  {
    "user_id" => 56,
    "date" => "2016-08-09T07:46:04.555-04:00"
  },
  {
    "user_id" => 57,
    "date" => "2016-08-08T06:35:44.345-04:00"
  },
]
```

I referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22736742/query-for-array-elements-inside-json-type) post and wrote a query which is working fine

```
SELECT *
FROM   posts, json_array_elements(edit_summary) as elem
WHERE  elem->>'date' BETWEEN '2016-08-07 00:00:00' AND '2016-08-10 23:59:59';
```

Now my question is there any way to do same rails way?

Answer (score 0):

You can execute the same query in Rails by providing raw SQL conditions.

However, I feel like edit summaries belong to another relation instead.

A `Post` `has_many` `EditSummary`, benefits:

- you'll be able to index dates and FK's.
- DB consistency (there's nothing preventing `user_id` from being a invalid id).
- separation
- DB validation