# Rails PSQL JSON query: find the nested array element at unknown position?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql

Please see an example here: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#json

How do I get all the records containing `"jack"` inside `change` array?

I can currently do it with such a query:

```
Event.where("payload #>> '{change,0}' = 'jack' ")
```

But what if I don't know the exact `"jack"`'s position (0 in this case) inside `change` array? How to rearrange the Rails PSQL query then?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Query for array elements inside JSON type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22736742/query-for-array-elements-inside-json-type), especially discussion of the `@>` (contains) operator (if you're using a jsonb column).