# Search for a json array in jsonb column having data as json array in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, jsonb

I have a jsonb column(gppermission) in my table doc which contains data as

```
[{"Deny": "true", "Allow": "false", "GroupName": "Group 1 "}, 
 {"Deny": "false", "Allow": "true", "GroupName": "Group 2 "}, 
 {"Deny": "false", "Allow": "true", "GroupName": "Group 3 "}, 
 {"Deny": "true", "Allow": "false", "GroupName": "Group 4 "}]
```

I need to search inside the this data for

```
{"Deny": "false", "Allow": "true", "GroupName": "Group 3 "}
```

I tried the below query. but no results :(

```
select * from doc as dc ,jsonb_array_elements(dc.gppermission) as e(gp) where e.gp = '{"Deny":"false","Allow":"true","GroupName":"Group 3"}'
```

Saw [Query for array elements inside JSON type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22736742/query-for-array-elements-inside-json-type) but it has an 'object' reference, my json array is different

Please help...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Query for array elements inside JSON type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22736742/query-for-array-elements-inside-json-type)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution, this may not be the only solution to do this.

```
select * from doc as dc ,jsonb_array_elements(dc.gppermission) as e(gp) where e.gp ->>'Deny'='false' and e.gp ->>'Allow'='true' and e.gp ->>'GroupName'='Group 1'
```