# Query JSON in Postgres

Tags: json, postgresql, groovy

I have some JSON in my postgres DB, it's in a table called `site_content`, the table has two rows, `id` and `content`, in `content` is where I store my JSON. I want to be able to find the a player given his id, my players are stored under the key `series` as this is the key needed to create my charts from JSON.

Here is the query I am currently using:

```
Blocking.get {
                sql.firstRow("""SELECT * from site_content where content -> 'playersContainer' -> 'series' -> 'id' = ${id} """)
            }.map { row ->
                log.info("row is: ${row}")
                if (row) {
                    objectMapper.readValue(row.getAt(0).toString(), Player)
                }
            }
        }
```

However I get back this error:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist:
>   json = character varying   Hint: No operator matches the given name
>   and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

Here is an example of my JSON:

```
"id": "${ID}",
    "team": {
        "id": "123",
        "name": "Shire Soldiers"
    },
    "playersContainer": {
        "series": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "name": "Nick",
                "teamName": "Shire Soldiers",
                "ratings": [
                    1,
                    5,
                    6,
                    9
                ],
                "assists": 17,
                "manOfTheMatches": 20,
                "cleanSheets": 1,
                "data": [
                    3,
                    2,
                    3,
                    5,
                    6
                ],
                "totalGoals": 19
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "name": "Pasty",
                "teamName": "Shire Soldiers",
                "ratings": [
                    6,
                    8,
                    9,
                    10
                ],
                "assists": 25,
                "manOfTheMatches": 32,
                "cleanSheets": 2,
                "data": [
                    3,
                    5,
                    7,
                    9,
                    10
                ],
                "totalGoals": 24
            }
        ]
    }
```

I am using Groovy for this project, but I guess it's just the general JSON postgres syntax I am having problems with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, that's a problem with SQL syntax. Correct you query:

```
select * from json_test where content->'playersContainer'->'series' @> '[{"id":"1"}]';
```

Full example:

```
CREATE TABLE json_test (
  content jsonb
);

insert into json_test(content) VALUES ('{"id": "1",
    "team": {
      "id": "123",
      "name": "Shire Soldiers"
    },
    "playersContainer": {
      "series": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "name": "Nick",
          "teamName": "Shire Soldiers",
          "ratings": [
            1,
            5,
            6,
            9
          ],
          "assists": 17,
          "manOfTheMatches": 20,
          "cleanSheets": 1,
          "data": [
            3,
            2,
            3,
            5,
            6
          ],
          "totalGoals": 19
        },
        {
          "id": "2",
          "name": "Pasty",
          "teamName": "Shire Soldiers",
          "ratings": [
            6,
            8,
            9,
            10
          ],
          "assists": 25,
          "manOfTheMatches": 32,
          "cleanSheets": 2,
          "data": [
            3,
            5,
            7,
            9,
            10
          ],
          "totalGoals": 24
        }
      ]
    }}');

select * from json_test where content->'playersContainer'->'series' @> '[{"id":"1"}]';
```

About [`@>`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html) operator. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22736742/query-for-array-elements-inside-json-type) might be also useful.

Comment: Thanks for the reply however I get this error

ERROR:  operator does not exist: json @> unknown

Comment: I am using postgres 9.4

Comment: I cast my content to jsonb instead of json and it worked, thank you!

Comment: Sorry it didn't work, using this query 

select content->'playersContainer'->'series' from site_content 
where content->'playersContainer'->'series' @> '[{"id":"1"}]';

I get back by players with an id of 1 and 2, I just want 1

Comment: @NickPocock, it seems here is the answer that might be helpful. In the second column in returns the seeked series element. Here's how it goes: select elem from json_test t, jsonb_array_elements(t.content->'playersContainer'->'series'‌​) as elem where elem->>'id'='1' ;

Answer (score -1):

May be it could help: Into the sql statement, I added this 'cast' where I have the json field:

```
INSERT INTO map_file(type, data)
VALUES (?, CAST(? AS json))
RETURNING id
```

the datatype of 'data' into map_file table is: json

Comment: You just copy-pasted your answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49307794/119775)?...