# Create Postgres JSONB Index on Array Sub-Object

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, indexing, jsonb

I have table `myTable` with a JSONB column `myJsonb` with a data structure that I want to index like:

```
{
  "myArray": [
    {
      "subItem": {
        "email": "bar@bar.com"
      }
    },
    {
      "subItem": {
        "email": "foo@foo.com"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to run indexed queries on `email` like:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE 'foo@foo.com' IN (
  SELECT lower(
      jsonb_array_elements(myjsonb -> 'myArray')
      -> 'subItem'
      ->> 'email'
  )
);
```

How do I create a Postgres JSONB index for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't need the `lower()` in there, the query can be simple and efficient:

```
SELECT *
FROM   mytable
WHERE  myjsonb -> 'myArray' @> '[{"subItem": {"email": "foo@foo.com"}}]'
```

Supported by a `jsonb_path_ops` index:

```
CREATE INDEX mytable_myjsonb_gin_idx ON mytable
USING  gin ((myjsonb -> 'myArray') jsonb_path_ops);
```

But the match is case-sensitive.

#### Case-insensitive!

If you need the search to match disregarding case, things get more complex.

You could use this query, similar to your original:

```
SELECT *
FROM   t
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   jsonb_array_elements(myjsonb -> 'myArray') arr
   WHERE  lower(arr #>>'{subItem, email}') = 'foo@foo.com'
   );
```

But I can't think of a good way to use an index for this.

**Instead**, I would use an expression index based on a function extracting an array of lower-case emails:

Function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_jsonb_arr_lower(_j jsonb, VARIADIC _path text[])
  RETURNS jsonb LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE AS
'SELECT jsonb_agg(lower(elem #>> _path)) FROM jsonb_array_elements(_j) elem';
```

Index:

```
CREATE INDEX mytable_email_arr_idx ON mytable
USING  gin (f_jsonb_arr_lower(myjsonb -> 'myArray', 'subItem', 'email') jsonb_path_ops);
```

Query:

```
SELECT *
FROM   mytable 
WHERE  f_jsonb_arr_lower(myjsonb -> 'myArray', 'subItem', 'email') @> '"foo@foo.com"';
```

While this works with an **untyped string literal** or with actual `jsonb` values, it stops working if you pass `text` or `varchar` (like in a prepared statement). Postgres does not know how to cast because the input is ambiguous. You need an explicit cast in this case:

```
... @> '"foo@foo.com"'::text::jsonb;
```

Or pass a simple string without enclosing double quotes and do the conversion to `jsonb` in Postgres:

```
... @> to_jsonb('foo@foo.com'::text);
```

Related, with more explanation:

- [Query for array elements inside JSON type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22736742/query-for-array-elements-inside-json-type/22737710#22737710)
- [Index for finding an element in a JSON array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404055/index-for-finding-an-element-in-a-json-array/18405706#18405706)

Comment: Case-insensitivity is a requirement; the latter appears to work. One workaround I was considering to make the former solution workable was to add a normalized column, but I couldn't figure out the syntax for `jsonb_array_elements` in an UPDATE statement to backfill the data for more than 1 `subItem`.

Comment: Hmm... I'm using JPA, but having trouble specifying the email as a parameter within the single-quotes...

Comment: @JJZabkar: You took note of the double-quotes (required for JSON strings) inside the single quotes (denoting Postgres string literals)? So the passed string has to come with surrounding double-quotes. Alternatively, you could extract a Postgres array consisiting of plain text strings. Recent example: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/193378/3684

Comment: Yes, took note, but I can't find the right syntax to parameterize it within a JPA nativeQuery. Since you've (quite elegantly) solved the main question here, I believe it's appropriate to move my secondary issue to a new thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47877601/spring-data-jpa-jsonb-paramaterization

Comment: Yes, fully agree. I think I may have an idea what's going wrong and appended some pointers above.

Comment: Yup, you were spot-on with the casting. Noted solution on the other thread with a few other tweaks. Thanks!