# Spring Data JPA JSONB Paramaterization

Tags: postgresql, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, jsonb, spring-el

What is the correct syntax (JPA, Spring Data, or SpEL) to convert this query into a Spring Data Repository `nativeQuery`?

```
SELECT *
FROM   mytable 
WHERE  f_jsonb_arr_lower(myjsonb -> 'myArray', 'subItem', 'email') 
 @> '"foo@foo.com"';
```

I want to use an input parameter instead of hard-coding `"foo@foo.com"`.

My model: Postgres `myTable` with a JSONB column `myJsonb`:

```
{
  "myArray": [
    {
      "subItem": {
        "email": "bar@bar.com"
      }
    },
    {
      "subItem": {
        "email": "foo@foo.com"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Index described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47822254/create-postgres-jsonb-index-on-array-sub-object).

The hard-coded version works:

```
@Query(value = 
        "SELECT m.* " +
        " FROM mytable AS m " +
        " WHERE f_jsonb_arr_lower(myjsonb -> 'myArray' ,'subItem', 'email') " + 
        "   @> '\"foo@foo.com\"' " +
        " ORDER BY ?#{#pageable} ", 
        // Spring Data nativeQueries with Pageable require a separate countQuery:
        countQuery = 
        "SELECT count(m.id) " +
        " FROM mytable AS m " +
        " WHERE f_jsonb_arr_lower(myjsonb -> 'myArray' ,'subItem', 'email') " +
        " @> '\"foo@foo.com\"' ",
        nativeQuery = true)
Page<MyTableEntity> findAllHardcodedPageable(Pageable pageable);
```

But trying to leverage the `lowercaseEmailAddress` parameter in a Spring Data repository nativeQuery does not work:

```
@Query(value = 
        "SELECT m.* " +
        " FROM mytable AS m " +
        " WHERE f_jsonb_arr_lower(myjsonb -> 'myArray' ,'subItem', 'email') " + 
        "   @> '\"?{lowercaseEmailAddress}\"' " +
        " ORDER BY ?#{#pageable} ", 
        countQuery = 
        "SELECT count(m.id) " +
        " FROM mytable AS m " +
        " WHERE f_jsonb_arr_lower(myjsonb -> 'myArray' ,'subItem', 'email') " +
        " @> '\"?{lowercaseEmailAddress}\"' ",
        nativeQuery = true)
Page<MyTableEntity> findAllByEmailPageable
  (String lowercaseEmailAddress, Pageable pageable);
```

In my Postgres query logging, I can see that the `lowercaseEmailAddress` parameter is never set:

```
LOG:  execute S_2: COMMIT
LOG:  execute S_3: BEGIN
LOG:  execute <unnamed>: SELECT count(m.id)  FROM mytable 
   AS m  WHERE f_jsonb_arr_lower(myjsonb -> 'myArray', 
   'subitem', 'email')  @> '"?1"' 
LOG:  execute S_11: ROLLBACK
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:

1) Pass only a double-quoted `String` to the spring data repository method:

```
String emailAddressWithDoubleQuotes = String.format("\"%s\"",emailAddress);
result = repository.findAllByEmailPageable(emailAddressWithDoubleQuotes, pageRequest).getContent();
```

2) The Spring Repository `@Query` needs to have the SpEL expression in parenthesis and be casted to `jsonb`:

```
static final String FIND_ALL_BY_EMAIL_QUERY = " FROM mytable AS m " +
        " WHERE f_jsonb_arr_lower(metadata -> 'myArray', 'subItem', 'email') " +
        " @> ( ?#{#lowercaseEmailAddress} )\\:\\:jsonb";
@Query( // only use 'ORDER BY #pageableWithNativeSort' on 'value' query:
        value = "SELECT m.* " + FIND_ALL_BY_EMAIL_QUERY + " ORDER BY ?#{#pageableWithNativeSort} ",
        // Spring Data nativeQueries with Pageable require a separate 'countQuery':
        countQuery = "SELECT count(m.id) " + FIND_ALL_BY_EMAIL_QUERY,
        nativeQuery = true)
Page<OrderEntity> findAllBysubItemEmail(
        @Param("lowercaseEmailAddress") String lowercaseEmailAddress,
        @Param("pageableWithNativeSort") Pageable pageableWithNativeSort);
```