# Select with filters on nested JSON array

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

Postgres 10: I have a table and a query below:

```
CREATE TABLE individuals (
    uid character varying(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    data jsonb
);

SELECT data->'files'  FROM individuals WHERE uid = 'PDR7073706'
```

It returns this structure:

```
[
{"date":"2017-12-19T22-35-49","type":"indiv","name":"PDR7073706_indiv_2017-12-19T22-35-49.jpeg"},
{"date":"2017-12-19T22-35-49","type":"address","name":"PDR7073706_address_2017-12-19T22-35-49.pdf"}
]
```

I'm struggling with adding two filters by date and time. Like (illegal pseudo-code!):

*WHERE 'type' = "indiv"*

or like:

*WHERE 'type' = "indiv" AND max('date')*

It is probably easy, but I can't crack this nut, and need your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming data type **`jsonb`** for lack of info.
Use the containment operator `@>` for the first clause (*WHERE 'type' = "indiv"*):

```
SELECT data->'files'
FROM   individuals
WHERE  uid = 'PDR7073706'
AND    data -> 'files' @> '[{"type":"indiv"}]';
```

Can be supported with various kinds of indexes. See:

- [Query for array elements inside JSON type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22736742/query-for-array-elements-inside-json-type/22737710#22737710)
- [Index for finding an element in a JSON array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404055/index-for-finding-an-element-in-a-json-array/18405706#18405706)

The second clause (*AND max('date')*) is more tricky. Assuming you mean:
*Get rows where the JSON array element with `"type":"indiv"` also has the latest `"date"`.*

```
SELECT i.*
FROM   individuals i
JOIN   LATERAL (
   SELECT *
   FROM   jsonb_array_elements(data->'files')
   ORDER  BY to_timestamp(value ->> 'date', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24-MI-SS') DESC NULLS LAST
   LIMIT  1
   ) sub ON sub.value -> 'type' = '"indiv"'::jsonb
WHERE  uid = 'PDR7073706'
AND    data -> 'files' @> '[{"type":"indiv"}]' -- optional; may help performance
```

`to_timestamp(value ->> 'date', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24-MI-SS')` is my educated guess on your undeclared timestamp format. [Details in the manual here.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html)

The last filter is redundant and optional. but it may help performance (a lot) if it is selective (only few rows qualify) and you have a matching index as advised:

```
AND    data -> 'files' @> '[{"type":"indiv"}]'
```

Related:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest record per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-record-per-user/25536748#25536748)
- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)
- [Update nth element of array using a WHERE clause](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/193390/update-nth-element-of-array-using-a-where-clause/193452#193452)

Comment: That a lot for you suggestion. You are right, I should have posted table schema, I'm updated the question. First query works great, but the second (complex) one troughs an error: 
ERROR: column "elem" does not exist LINE 8: ) sub ON elem -> 'type' = '"indiv"'::jsonb ^ SQL state: 42703 Character: 223

Would you mind helping finding what's wrong with it?

Comment: @uzla: Oops, I changed the column name when posting. The default result column name of `jsonb_array_elements()` is `value`. Using that now.

Comment: Thanks a lot! IT works! And thanks for corrections! I learn something new everyday:-)