# PostgreSQL query of JSONB array by nested object

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have the following array JSON data structure:

```
{ arrayOfObjects: 
    [
        {
            "fieldA": "valueA1", 
            "fieldB": { "fieldC": "valueC", "fieldD": "valueD" }
        },
        {
            "fieldA": "valueA", 
            "fieldB": { "fieldC": "valueC", "fieldD": "valueD" }
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to select all records where fieldD matches my criteria (and fieldC is unknown).  I've see similar answers such as [Query for array elements inside JSON type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22736742/query-for-array-elements-inside-json-type) but there the field being queried is a simple string (akin to searching on fieldA in my example) where my problem is that I would like to query based on an object within an object within the array.

I've tried something like `select * from myTable where jsonData -> 'arrayOfObjects' @> '[ { "fieldB": { "fieldD": "valueD" } } ]' )` but that doesn't seem to work.

How can I achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute a "contains" query on the JSONB field directly and pass the minimum you're looking for:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE json_data @> '{"arrayOfObjects": [{"fieldB": {"fieldD": "valueD"}}]}'::JSONB;
```

This of course assumes that fieldD is always nested under fieldB, but that's a fairly low bar to clear in terms of schema consistency.

Comment: Can you please post how this can be done using hibernate criteria builder