# Filtering the JSON data stored in Postgres based on key-value pairs

Tags: sql, postgresql, go, indexing, jsonb

I have a JSON object stored as **JSONB** in my **Postgres** database under the column name **cart**.
This is the cart data for 2 users

```
"items": [
 {
   "name": "T-shirt",
   "price": 250,
   "item_id": 111,
   "quantity": 1
 },
 {
   "name": "Trousers",
   "price": 600,
   "item_id": 222,
   "quantity": 1
 }
]
}

&&&&

{
"items": [
 {
   "name": "Jeans",
   "price": 250,
   "item_id": 333,
   "quantity": 1
 },
 {
   "name": "Trousers",
   "price": 600,
   "item_id": 444,
   "quantity": 1
 }
]
}
```

This data is stored under The column name **cart**. I tried using Gin indexes but wasn't clear about what i was doing.
How should i be able to query The data such that i can find the list of all users that have trousers as an item in their **cart** in **Postgres**?
Also, i am New to this implementation and keen to learn So Would be helpful If the implementations are made through **Golang**.
Thanks, Pushkar Singh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
USING gin ((cart->'items') jsonb_path_ops);

SELECT * FROM order2 WHERE cart->'items' @> '[{"name":"Trousers"}]';
```

Refrences :

[Query for array elements inside JSON type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22736742/query-for-array-elements-inside-json-type)

[Index for finding an element in a JSON array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404055/index-for-finding-an-element-in-a-json-array/18405706#18405706)