# Select rows where items in a JSON array has a specific value

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I have a table with a JSONB column. The column contains a number of topics as an array: Example:

```sql
select id, topics from c;
```

```
   id    |                                                                 topics
---------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 7783263 | [{"id": "ddded8f7-1a72-4e43-b040-86a01e82d2c6", "name": "Finance"}]
 7783556 | [{"id": "7bad8662-a07b-45c5-bea5-1aa6050c0dfb", "name": "Politics"}]
 7783795 |
 7785318 | [{"id": "7bad8662-a07b-45c5-bea5-1aa6050c0dfb", "name": "Politics"}, {"id": "ddded8f7-1a72-4e43-b040-86a01e82d2c6", "name": "Finance"}]
```

I have tried the `@>` operator and some others but to no help. I need to be able to select all the items that has either one specific topic like `"Finance"` or several such as `["Finance", "Politics"]`.

I tried `topics @> '{"name": ["Finance"]}'` as an example, but that didn't work.

Comment: This might get you started: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22736742/query-for-array-elements-inside-json-type

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use an OR condition:

```
select *
from the_table
where topics @> '[{"name": "Finance"}]'
   or topics @> '[{"name": "Politics"}]'
;
```

If you are using Postgres 12 or later, you can also collect all names into a (JSON) array and use the `?|` operator:

```
select *
from the_table
where jsonb_path_query_array(topics, '$.name') ?| array['Finance', 'Politics']
```