# Checking existence of value inside JSON array

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I've found the solution for more complex than this but I'm not able to make this work...

I've a column called **data** of type **json**. The JSON structure is as follows:

```
{"actions": ["action1","action2","action3", ..., "actionN"]}
```

So, let's say I've 3 rows with the following data:

```
{"actions": ["work","run"]}
{"actions": ["run","eat","sleep", 'walk']}
{"actions": ["eat","run","work"]}
```

I want to retrieve the rows where **work** is included in **actions** array.

I've tried something similar to what is posted here:
[Query for element of array in JSON column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19568123/query-for-element-of-array-in-json-column), but since each element inside the array is just a json string, I got stuck there.

Then, I tried something like:

```
SELECT * from table t WHERE 'work' in ...
```

but this also failed to get the values as an string array to put it there.

Using PostgreSql 9.3.

Comment: Somehow use http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54283/how-to-turn-json-array-into-postgres-array with unnest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using the `json` type, which is just a string internally, the simplest solution is:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE strpos(data::text, 'work') > 0;
```

It defeats the purpose of using `json` in the first place, but it is (very likely) faster than the json parser in this simple case.

A json solution would be:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT *, unnest(data->"actions")::text AS action FROM table) AS foo
WHERE action = 'work';
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought there was a simpler solution and this definitely works.