# Query data inside an attribute array in a json column in Postgres 9.6

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a table say types, which had a JSON column, say location that looks like this:

```
{ "attribute":[
  {
    "type": "state",
    "value": "CA"
  },
  {
    "type": "distance",
    "value": "200.00"
  } ...
  ]
  }
```

Each row in the table has the data, and all have the  "type": "state" in it. I want to just extract the value of  "type": "state" from every row in the table, and put it in a new column. I checked out several questions on SO, like:

- [Query for element of array in JSON column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19568123/query-for-element-of-array-in-json-column/19868697#19868697)
- [Index for finding an element in a JSON array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404055/index-for-finding-an-element-in-a-json-array?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Query for array elements inside JSON type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22736742/query-for-array-elements-inside-json-type)

but could not get it working. I do not need to query on this. I need the value of this column. I apologize in advance if I missed something.

Comment: Is that always in the first array element? Can there be multiple array elements with `type = state`?

Comment: Not within the same row. Every row will only have one attribute with  type = state.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ```
> create table t(data json);
> insert into t values('{"attribute":[{"type": "state","value": "CA"},{"type": "distance","value": "200.00"}]}'::json); 
>
> select elem->>'value' as state
> from t, json_array_elements(t.data->'attribute') elem
> where elem->>'type' = 'state';
> ```
>
> ```
> | state |
> | :---- |
> | CA    |
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=e533e1b3b84878b8e7b5bd89cc85e668)*

Answer (score 2):

I mainly use Redshift where there is a built-in function to do this.  So on the off-chance you're there, check it out.
[redshift docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT.html)

It looks like Postgres has a similar function set: 
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html

I think you'll need to chain three functions together to make this work.

```
SELECT 
   your_field::json->'attribute'->0->'value'
FROM
    your_table
```

What I'm trying is a json extract by key name, followed by a json array extract by index (always the 1st, if your example is consistent with the full data), followed finally by another extract by key name.

**Edit: got it working for your example**

```
SELECT 
  '{ "attribute":[
  {
    "type": "state",
    "value": "CA"
  },
  {
    "type": "distance",
    "value": "200.00"
  }
  ]
  }'::json->'attribute'->0->'value'
```

Returns `"CA"`

**2nd edit: nested querying**
@McNets is the right, better answer.  But in this dive, I discovered you can nest queries in Postgres!  How frickin' cool!

I stored the json as a text field in a dummy table and successfully ran this:

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT value FROM json_to_recordset(
    my_column::json->'attribute') as x(type text, value text)
  WHERE
    type = 'state'
    )
FROM dummy_table
```

Comment: Thank you @a_horse_with_no_name, but I cannot rely on index. It can be at any location within the array.