# Query jsonb array in POSTGRESQL 9.6

Tags: json, postgresql

This is my json :

```
[{"state":"terminated"}]
```

How can I query this array to get the state in a where clause ?

I'd like to query my table and get every rows with the colunm containing a state equals to "terminated"

My table :

```
id     |   info
 1     |  [{"state":"terminated"}]
```

What I've tried :

```
select * from "myTable"
where info->>'state' = 'terminated'
```

But it doesn't return any rows.

I checked in table I have a row with a state ="terminated"

EDIT :

The "info" column can contains more object than now.

Example :

```
 [{"state":"terminated"},{"anotherKey","anotherValue"}]
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Query for element of array in JSON column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19568123/query-for-element-of-array-in-json-column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first create Index

```
CREATE INDEX docs_data_idx ON myTable USING GIN (info jsonb_path_ops);
```

then

```
select * from myTable WHERE  info @> '[ { "state":"terminated"} ]';
```