# PostgreSQL - check if column exists and nest condition statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, conditional-statements, case

Transactions column's names in below code are dynamicaly generated (so it means that sometimes particular name/column doesn't exist). Using this select it finishes successfully only in case when every of those names exists, if not, I got error like this (example):

> Error(s), warning(s): 42703: column "TransactionA" does not exist

```
SELECT  
             *,
               ((CASE WHEN "TransactionA" IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE "TransactionA" END) - 
               (CASE WHEN "TransactionB" IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE "TransactionB" END) +
               (CASE WHEN "TransactionC" IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE "TransactionC" END)) AS "Account_balance"
        FROM Summary ORDER BY id;
```

Could you tell me please how can I check first if the column exists and then how can I nest another CASE statement or other condition statement to make it working in a correct way?

Comment: `COALESCE()`will greatly simplify your expression.BTW: what do you mean by `...if a column exists...`

Comment: But using just COALESCE() there's still error appearing that the column doesn't exist. By saying "if a column exists" I mean it's generated in some function and not every time the column names are the same (it's always 5 columns, but 2 columns can have a few different names - I know what names they can have, but it's randomly chosen, so 1 time it can be TransactionX and other time it can be TransactionY.

Comment: You can only use existing column names. But you may need `COALESCE` *on top of that* to catch `NULL` values from existing columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can build any query dynamically with information from the Postgres catalog tables. `pg_attribute` in your case. Alternatively, use the information schema. See:

- [Query to return output column names and data types of a query, table or view](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/75124/3684)
- [How to check if a table exists in a given schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582500/how-to-check-if-a-table-exists-in-a-given-schema/24089729#24089729)

Basic query to see which of the given columns exist in a given table:

```
SELECT attname
FROM   pg_attribute a
WHERE  attrelid = 'public.summary'::regclass  --  tbl here
AND    NOT attisdropped
AND    attnum > 0
AND    attname IN ('TransactionA', 'TransactionB', 'TransactionC');  -- columns here
```

Building on this, you can have Postgres generate your whole query. While being at it, look up whether columns are defined `NOT NULL`, in which case they don't need `COALESCE`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_build_query(_tbl regclass, _columns json)
  RETURNS text AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _expr text;
BEGIN

SELECT INTO _expr
       string_agg (op || CASE WHEN attnotnull
                              THEN quote_ident(attname)
                              ELSE format('COALESCE(%I, 0)', attname) END
                 , '')
FROM  (
   SELECT j->>'name' AS attname
        , CASE WHEN j->>'op' = '-' THEN ' - ' ELSE ' + ' END AS op
   FROM   json_array_elements(_columns) j
   ) j
JOIN   pg_attribute a USING (attname)
WHERE  attrelid = _tbl
AND    NOT attisdropped
AND    attnum > 0;

IF NOT FOUND THEN
   RAISE EXCEPTION 'No column found!'; -- or more info
END IF;

RETURN
'SELECT *,' || _expr || ' AS "Account_balance"
FROM   ' || _tbl || '
ORDER  BY id;';

END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The table itself is parameterized, too. May or may not be useful for you. The only assumption is that every table has an `id` column for the `ORDER BY`. Related:

- [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)

I pass columns names and the associated operator as JSON document for flexibility. Only `+` or `-` are expected as operator. Input is safely concatenated to make SQL injection impossible.About `json_array_elements()`:

- [Query for element of array in JSON column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19568123/query-for-element-of-array-in-json-column/19868697#19868697)

Example call:

```
SELECT f_build_query('summary', '[{"name":"TransactionA"}
                                , {"name":"TransactionB", "op": "-"}
                                , {"name":"TransactionC"}]');
```

Returns the according valid query string, like:

```
SELECT *, + COALESCE("TransactionA", 0) - COALESCE("TransactionB", 0) AS "Account_balance"
FROM   summary
ORDER  BY id;
```

`"TransactionC"` isn't there in this case. If both existing columns happen to be `NOT NULL`, you get instead:

```
SELECT *, + "TransactionA" - "TransactionB" AS "Account_balance"
FROM   summary
ORDER  BY id;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=09756fb99d386fbd3b99d47a41d35460)*

You *could* execute the generated query in the function immediately and return result rows directly. But that's hard as your return type is a combination of a table rows (unknown until execution time?) *plus* additional column, and SQL demands to know the return type in advance. For just `id` and sum (stable return type), it would be easy ...

It's odd that your CaMeL-case column names are double-quoted, but the CaMeL-case table name is not. By mistake? See:

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)

#### How to pass column names containing single quotes?

Addressing additional question from comment.

If someone used column names containing single quotes by mistake:

```
CREATE TABLE madness (
  id int PRIMARY KEY
, "'TransactionA'" numeric NOT NULL  -- you wouldn't do that ...
, "'TransactionC'" numeric NOT NULL
);
```

For the above function, the JSON value is passed as quoted string literal. If that string is enclosed in single-quotes, escape contained single-quotes by doubling them up. This is required on top of valid JSON format:

```
SELECT f_build_query('madness', '[{"name":"''TransactionA''"}
                                , {"name":"TransactionB", "op": "-"}
                                , {"name":"TransactionC"}]');  --
```

(`"''TransactionA''"` finds a match, `"TransactionC"` does not.)

Or use dollar quoting instead:

```
SELECT f_build_query('madness', $$[{"name":"'TransactionA'"}
                                , {"name":"TransactionB", "op": "-"}
                                , {"name":"TransactionC"}]$$);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f89c793621d56afb7d959b98690015b5)* with added examples

See:

- [Insert text with single quotes in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316953/insert-text-with-single-quotes-in-postgresql/12320729#12320729)

Comment: Could you tell me how can I write column name which has single quotes, please? I mean while calling function f_build_query. It looks like this: {"name":"TransactionA"}, but what if I have column name which is named like: 'TransactionA' and not like I said before: TransactionA? I know it makes no sense to use quotes in name of column, but in this case I can't change it

Comment: @RafauYT: Consider the addendum above.

Comment: [So do you have your answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/169168)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `id` is a unique id in `summary`, then you can use the following trick:

```
SELECT s.*,
       (COALESCE("TransactionA", 0) -
        COALESCE("TransactionB", 0) +
        COALESCE("TransactionC", 0)
       ) AS Account_balance
FROM (SELECT id, . . .   -- All columns except the TransactionX columns
FROM (SELECT s.*, 
             (SELECT TransactionA FROM summary s2 WHERE s2.id = s.id) as TransactionA,
             (SELECT TransactionB FROM summary s2 WHERE s2.id = s.id) as TransactionB,
             (SELECT TransactionC FROM summary s2 WHERE s2.id = s.id) as TransactionC
            FROM Summary s
           ) s CROSS JOIN
           (VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL)) v(TransactionA, TransactionB, TransactionC)
      ) s
ORDER BY s.id;
```

The trick here is that the correlated subqueries do not qualify the `TransactionA`.  If the value is defined for `summary`, then that will be used.  If not, it will come from the `values()` clause in the outer query.

This is a bit of a hack, but it can be handy under certain circumstances.

Comment: Could you tell me please, if there should be 2 tables: summary and Summary? If yes, why? And what means 'v' letter in front of brackets which include columns' names (transactions) inside?

Comment: @RafauYT . . . I have no idea why you are asking about two tables.  Identifiers in SQL are usually case-insensitive.  The `v` is a table alias.

Comment: I understand. Could you tell me please, how can I type columns' names to your code, if the names are with sinqle quotes? The names look like this: 'Transaction A'. Does in COALESCE should it look like this?: "'Transaction A'" and with others like this?: 'Transaction A'? Sorry if the questions are not so smart, but I was trying many possibilities and nothing works yet.

Comment: @RafauYT . . . Column names should *never* be in single quotes.  *Only* use single quotes for string and date literals.  Use double quotes for identifiers that need to be escaped -- or better yet, use names that don't need to be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

Check this example:

```
UPDATE yourtable1 
SET yourcolumn = (
    CASE 
        WHEN setting.value IS NOT NULL
            THEN CASE WHEN replace(setting.value,'"','') <> '' THEN replace(setting.value,'"','') ELSE NULL END
        ELSE NULL
    END
)::TIME FROM (SELECT value FROM yourtable2 WHERE key = 'ABC') AS setting;
```