# Subquery for element of JSON column

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a big JSON data in one column called `response_return` in a Postgres DB, with a response like:

```
{ 
   "customer_payment":{ 
      "OrderId":"123456789",
      "Customer":{ 
         "Full_name":"Francis"
      },
      "Payment":{ 
         "AuthorizationCode":"9874565",
         "Recurrent":false,
         "Authenticate":false,
         ...
      }
   }
}
```

I tried to use Postgres functions like `->` ,`->>` ,`#>`  or `@>`  to walk through headers to achieve **AuthorizationCode** for a query.

When I use `->`  in *customer_payment* in a SELECT, returns all after them. If I try with OrderId, it's returned NULL.

The alternatives and sources:

[Using The JSON Datatype In PostgreSQL](https://datavirtuality.com/blog-json-in-postgresql/)

Operator ->

- Allows you to select an element based on its name.
- Allows you to select an element within an array based on its index.
- Can be used sequentially: ::json->'elementL'->'subelementM'->…->'subsubsubelementN'.
- Return type is json and the result cannot be used with functions and operators that require a string-based datatype. But the result can be used with operators and functions that require a json datatype.

[Query for element of array in JSON column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19568123/query-for-element-of-array-in-json-column/19868697#19868697)

This is not helpful because I don't want filter and do not believe that need to transform to array.

Comment: Hi @a_horse_with_no_name, thanks for asking. My Postgres version is 11.6 and I need AuthorizationCode or Recurrent, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to get a single attribute, you can use:

```
select response_return -> 'customer_payment' -> 'Payment' ->> 'AuthorizationCode'
from the_table;
```

You need to use `->` for the intermediate access to the keys (to keep the JSON type) and `->>` for the last key to return the value as a string.

Alternatively you can provide the path to the element as an array and use `#>>`

```
select response_return #>> array['customer_payment', 'Payment', 'AuthorizationCode']
from the_table;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=b11131ea20d914c44393aba9c50e47f7)

Comment: Thanks a_horse_with_no_name! It's Worked. 

The catch is use -> and after ->>.