# Postgres JSON selecting a row by list

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-json

I have a table that has a JSON list as one of its values. The column name is `list_order` and the value would be something like: `[1,2,3]`.

I am having trouble doing a `WHERE` comparison to select by `list_order`. In pure SQL, it would be: `SELECT * FROM table_name list_order=[1,2,3];`

The closest example I found was this: [How do I query using fields inside the new PostgreSQL JSON datatype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10560394/how-do-i-query-using-fields-inside-the-new-postgresql-json-datatype/10560761#10560761). However, this grabs the value of a key in the JSON where the JSON is a dictionary and not a list. I've tried modifying it to suit my need but it did not work.

Any suggestions? Is that even possible? Why is not documented? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I need to compare it as text:

`"SELECT * FROM table WHERE list_order::text='[1,2,3]';`