# Postgres JSON data type Rails query

Tags: json, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-postgresql, psql

I am using Postgres' json data type but want to do a query/ordering with data that is nested within the json.

I want to order or query with .where on the json data type. For example, I want to query for users that have a follower count > 500 or I want to order by follower or following count.

Thanks!

Example:

```
model User

data: {
     "photos"=>[
       {"type"=>"facebook", "type_id"=>"facebook", "type_name"=>"Facebook", "url"=>"facebook.com"}
      ], 
     "social_profiles"=>[
         {"type"=>"vimeo", "type_id"=>"vimeo", "type_name"=>"Vimeo", "url"=>"http://vimeo.com/", "username"=>"v", "id"=>"1"},
         {"bio"=>"I am not a person, but a series of plants", "followers"=>1500, "following"=>240, "type"=>"twitter", "type_id"=>"twitter", "type_name"=>"Twitter", "url"=>"http://www.twitter.com/", "username"=>"123", "id"=>"123"}
     ]
}
```

Comment: PostgrSQL 9.3 is what I am using

Comment: OK, and did you look at the json operators like `->` ?

Comment: `Record.where("data -> 'status' = 200 ")` not working

Comment: Ah, you want to write it in Rails/ActiveRecord syntax. In that case ... *runs rapidly away*.

Comment: Ha :D How can this be done with pure Psql queries?

Comment: Your json is invalid, not keen on going through and fixing it. It's also going to be tricky because of the nonuniform structure, with the `social_profiles` entries being different. You'll probably need a `LATERAL` query over `json_each`.

Comment: The json above is just an example, but the way it's stored is much more different.

Answer (score 169, accepted):

For any who stumbles upon this. I have come up with a list of queries using ActiveRecord and Postgres' JSON data type. Feel free to edit this to make it more clear.

Documentation to the JSON operators used below: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html.

```
# Sort based on the Hstore data:
Post.order("data->'hello' DESC")
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [
    #<Post id: 4, data: {"hi"=>"23", "hello"=>"22"}>, 
    #<Post id: 3, data: {"hi"=>"13", "hello"=>"21"}>, 
    #<Post id: 2, data: {"hi"=>"3", "hello"=>"2"}>, 
    #<Post id: 1, data: {"hi"=>"2", "hello"=>"1"}>]> 

# Where inside a JSON object:
Record.where("data ->> 'likelihood' = '0.89'")

# Example json object:
r.column_data
=> {"data1"=>[1, 2, 3], 
    "data2"=>"data2-3", 
    "array"=>[{"hello"=>1}, {"hi"=>2}], 
    "nest"=>{"nest1"=>"yes"}} 

# Nested search:
Record.where("column_data -> 'nest' ->> 'nest1' = 'yes' ")

# Search within array:
Record.where("column_data #>> '{data1,1}' = '2' ")

# Search within a value that's an array:
Record.where("column_data #> '{array,0}' ->> 'hello' = '1' ")
# this only find for one element of the array. 

# All elements:
Record.where("column_data ->> 'array' LIKE '%hello%' ") # bad
Record.where("column_data ->> 'array' LIKE ?", "%hello%") # good
```

Comment: There's a helpful answer here that deals with multiple levels:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23609331/how-do-i-search-over-a-json-type-of-postgres-in-multilevels-using-active-record  and the logic behind it here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html

Comment: Thanks @AmeetWadhwani I am probably going to write a blog post on this topic. Stay tuned for other coming across this answer!

Comment: @MohamedElMahallawy Can you help with this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27697489/use-where-queries-in-jsonb-datatype-in-rails-postgres. I am not able to figure out where query for a row which has an array of json elements without a key.

Comment: When searching within an array, what does the latter 1 mean in `{data1,1}`?

Comment: `Record.where("column_data ->> 'array' LIKE '%hello%' ")` is OK. `Record.where("column_data ->> 'array' LIKE '%#{user_input}%' ")` is bad. That's where you need the SQL parameter: `Record.where("column_data ->> 'array' LIKE '%?%' ", user_input)`

Comment: my json is like this `[{"id": 6,"name": "PGP - DATA SCIENCE AND ENGINEERING","code": "PGPDSE"},{"id": 36,"name": "PGP - Strategic Digital Marketing","code": "PGPSDM"}]`  how will I search for such record where code is PGPSDM

Answer (score 8):

According to this http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#json
there's a difference in using `->` and `->>`:

```
# db/migrate/20131220144913_create_events.rb
create_table :events do |t|
  t.json 'payload'
end

# app/models/event.rb
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
end

# Usage
Event.create(payload: { kind: "user_renamed", change: ["jack", "john"]})

event = Event.first
event.payload # => {"kind"=>"user_renamed", "change"=>["jack", "john"]}

## Query based on JSON document
# The -> operator returns the original JSON type (which might be an object), whereas ->> returns text
Event.where("payload->>'kind' = ?", "user_renamed")
```

So you should try `Record.where("data ->> 'status' = 200 ")` or the operator that suits your query (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html).

Answer (score 3):

Your question doesn't seem to correspond to the data you've shown, but if your table is named `users` and `data` is a field in that table with JSON like `{count:123}`, then the query

`SELECT * WHERE data->'count' > 500 FROM users`

will work. Take a look at your database schema to make sure you understand the layout and check that the query works before complicating it with Rails conventions.

Comment: This doesn't work for me in Postgres 9.3.3 unless I cast the JSON result to text and then to an integer: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE (data->'count')::text::integer > 500;`

Answer (score 3):

JSON filtering in Rails

```
Event.create( payload: [{ "name": 'Jack', "age": 12 },
                                 { "name": 'John', "age": 13 },
                                 { "name": 'Dohn', "age": 24 }]

Event.where('payload @> ?', '[{"age": 12}]')
#You can also filter by name key
Event.where('payload @> ?', '[{"name": "John"}]')
#You can also filter by {"name":"Jack", "age":12}
Event.where('payload @> ?', {"name":"Jack", "age":12}.to_json)
```

You can find more about this [here](https://www.cstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails/how-to-query-postgresqls-json-fields-from-rails)