# Search over a nested / multi-level Postgres JSON type using Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql, activerecord

Suppose I have the json object below

```
:response_body => {
    "status" => "ok",
    "um" => {
        "a" => "a",
        "b" => {
            "c" => "ok"
        }
    }
}
```

Example search:

```
LogService.where(response_body: {"status" => "ok"})
```

Answer (score 18):

If you are using the Postgres as database and the column really is a json type, you can use a search in Rails like this:

```
LogService.where("response_body#>>'{status}' = 'ok'")
```

This #>> will walk over the json path and make the search.
If you use only #> (with just one >), it will return the remaing json.

Another example, if you want to get the "c" => "ok"

```
LogService.where("response_body#>>'{um, b, c}' = 'ok'")
```

I think that´s it.