# first_or_initialize not working on json type column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to use `first_or_initialize` on a table having a `json` type column as :

`A.where("name=? and email=? and address->>'city'=? and address->>'state'=?", "John", "john@gmail.com", "New York", "New York").first_or_initialize`

But, this doesn't seem to work. Any idea if we can use this on such a table?

Comment: what error did you get?? please add errors

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
A.where("'name'=? and 'email'=? and 'address.city'=? and 'address.state'=?", "John", "john@gmail.com", "New York", "New York").first_or_initialize
```

I think this should help you..

Comment: what is the `address` in your case?

Comment: It's a column of json type.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your request is correct according [Rails guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#json)
As they say :

```
  Query based on JSON document
  The -> operator returns the original JSON type (which might be an object), whereas ->> returns text
```

What is the return of the query (without .first_or_initialize)?
An error, an empty array ?

These posts may help you to build the query you want : [Post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22667401/postgres-json-data-type-rails-query), [Post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23609331/how-do-i-search-over-a-json-type-of-postgres-in-multilevels-using-active-record), [PostgresqlHelp](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html)

Edit : Sorry, I misunderstood the question

––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––

If the request is the problem, you can try this: (from here [Rails guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-eager-loaded-associations))

```
A.includes(:address).where(name: "John", email: "john@gmail.com", address: {city: "New York", state: "New York"})
```

If the request is not the problem, could you give us more information on the error ?

Comment: This doesn't work as address is not an association with A.