# Rails 4: how to implement a column with multiple elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-associations

I'm creating a web application similar to LinkedIn using Ruby on Rails (rails 4), and I'm trying to add a "skills" column in the User table. Each user can have multiple skills, I want to be able to categorize users by skills.

I could either have the "skills" column be of type array (a string array, to be exact), or I could have a new model for skills and make associations (using has_many). Which would be better, or is there a nicer solution?

Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest the skills model... it gives you the advantage of easily collating all users with a given skill.

Comment: typist == Skill.find_by_name("typing"); typist.users

Comment: What database system are you using? Nosql solutions support this pretty easily, otherwise you can store arrays or hashes in some DB systems like Postgres. Though I agree with @SteveTurczyn and use a different model

Comment: Maybe you can try this: https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on  it uses the second approach (model for skills) but lets you to use as your first approach (an string)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should definitely go with the Model-based Skill solution instead of a serialized Array or any other solution:

- You can find easily Users from one/several Skill (with serialized array, that's a big adventure)
- Better standards between the differents skills in your DB:

  - with serialized Array, you cannot really control the case-sensitivity, typo errors, etc.
  - with a Skill model, you can easily implement a search-alike method (kind of **like how Stackoverflow deals with the Tags** about your post), tons of gems already exist for that purpose

The global relation config would be like :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users_skills
  has_many :skills, through: :users_skills

class UsersSkill < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :skill
  validates :user_id, :skill_id, presence: true

class Skill < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users_skills
  has_many :users, through: :users_skills
```

With this, very easy to find Users from Skill, and vice-versa:

```
web_developpers = Skill.where(name: 'Web developper').first.users
johns_skills = User.where(name: 'John').first.skills
```

---

**What if tomorrow your boss want you to add a feature like "preferred skill"** or "best skill"?  Or just a way to "order" (set a hierarchy between) a User's skills?

Just add a boolean column `best` on the join table (`users_skills`)

```
User.first.skills.where(users_skills: { best: true })
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Postgresql?

Then you can use the [JSON data type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html)

I wrote a question and an answer for it here:

[Postgres JSON data type Rails query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22667401/postgres-json-data-type-rails-query)

You can have column `skills`

With JSON within it as `{skills: [1,2,3,4]}`