# rails AR query filtering records using postgres json data type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

My postgres json data looks like this:

```
changes: {"data"=>[nil, {"margin"=>0.0, "target"=>0.77777}]}
```

The field name is `changes` and it's a postgres json data type.

How do I write an active record query to check for rows where `data` has a key named `margin`?

For example, the first record would be included while the second would not:

```
# record 1
changes: {"data"=>[nil, {"margin"=>0.0, "target"=>0.77777}]}
# record 2
changes: {"data"=>[nil, {"foo"=>0.0, "target"=>0.77777}]}
```

I've tried something like the following but it's not working:

```
ModelName.where("changes -> 'data' ?| array[:keys]", keys: ['margin'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer:

```
ModelName.where("changes -> 'data' -> 1 ? 'margin'")
```

The query logic is something like...in the `changes` field, move to object `data`, get second element (zero based index), see if it contains a key named `margin`.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is what I [found](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#json)

> Query based on JSON document
>
> The -> operator returns the original JSON type (which might be an object), whereas ->> returns text

Also, this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22667401/postgres-json-data-type-rails-query) is probably what you look for.

Maybe try something like

```
ModelName.where("changes->>'margin' > -1")
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. After some experimenting I figured out how to do it.