# Search through jsonb column in ActiveRecord

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

My User model have jsonb column which names is `raw`. It looks like this:

```
{"client"=>{"tokens"=>["asdasd"]}}
```

Now I want to find a user by a token which is in `raw["client"]["tokens"]`. How can I do that?

Comment: Try `User.where("raw->'client'->'tokens' = ?", 'your token here')`

Comment: This might be relevant to what you were looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22667401/postgres-json-data-type-rails-query

Comment: If you need search by one token from `tokens` array, you have to use `@>`: `User.find_by("raw->'client'->'tokens' @> ?", ['token'].to_json)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually first craft such queries in a SQL console and then convert it to ActiveRecord.

You can navigate hash keys in Postgres. The query

```
SELECT
  raw #> '{client,tokens}'
FROM users
```

will return just the `tokens` array from that path. Now we will need to check if it contains the value we are looking for. The query

```
SELECT
  raw #> '{client,tokens}' ? 'asdasd'
FROM users
```

will select `t` for those row that have a matching token. Now you can move this to the `WHERE` section:

```
SELECT
*
FROM users
WHERE  raw #> '{client,tokens}' ? 'asdasd'
```

And if this selects what you expect, then you can convert it to AR:

```
User.where("config #> '{client, tokens}' ? :token", token: 'asdasd')
```

Note that I can not use `?` for parameter substitution and use `:token` instead. Also note that this only works in JSONB (Postgres 9.4+ https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE)

Update:

You should(tm) (I have not tested this) get along with:

```
CREATE INDEX index_tokens ON users USING GIN ((raw #> '{client, tokens}'));
```

See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/datatype-json.html#JSON-INDEXING for more details

Update2:

Another way to query would be:

```
raw @> '{"client": {"tokens": ["asdasd"]}}'
```

Which should be able to use a simple `GIN` index on the raw column (which uses more space than the expression index described above).

`CREATE INDEX index_user_raw ON users USING GIN (raw)`

Again: details see the JSON INDEXING link above. And use a Query Visualizer to see the differences. I like http://tatiyants.com/pev

Comment: What index should be defined for such where?