# Postgres JSON Rails Query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a record that looks like this:
`{ properties: [1,2] }`

I want to search to find the field where the properties match exactly.

`Record.where("(query)")`

So far I tried things I found from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22667401/postgres-json-data-type-rails-query) including

`"properties#>>'{array,0}' = '1'"`

to try to get the first element of an array to match.

I just don't understand the query interface for postgres columns at all. Can someone help me out? How do I search for an array with contents I know I want to match exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access elements of an array, use their numeric index with the format `fieldname->>index`

So the answer to the original query is:

```
properties ->>0 is '1' and properties->>1 is '2'
```