# how to set type for jsonb[] for play-scala anorm pgsql

Tags: json, postgresql, scala, anorm

I am building a survey application in scala/play framework, and am using postgres9.4 and anorm. I am using jsonb as a datatype in other places but in one location I want to use jsonb[] thinking that this type is an array of jsonb values. My json structure is like the following:

```
[
    {"guitar":{"passion":3,
               "expertise":5,
               "willingToTeach":false,
               "lookingForOthers":false
              }
     },
     {"soccer":{"passion":3,
                "expertise":3,
                "willingToTeach":true,
                "lookingForOthers":true
                }
     }
]
```

Here each interest is a json structure. I have been able to add json response values to other columns in pgsql using `jsonb`as the data type, but when I try to use `jsonb[]` I get complaints: `[PSQLException: Unknown type jsonb[].]` In pgadmin3 it literally shows my this exact data type: `jsonb[]` for the column I am trying to insert into. In my anorm insert code I have tried setting the type:

```
val pgObject = new PGobject();
pgObject.setType("jsonb")
```

But then I get this error:

```
[PSQLException: ERROR: column "passions" is of type jsonb[] but expression is of type jsonb
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
  Position: 43]
```

I have tried looking this up but I can't even seem to find what all string values I can use as an argument for pgObject.setType(). I am also unsure how I would go about casting the expression from `jsonb` to `jsonb[]` any other way than setting the type using the setType() method.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why would you use `jsonb[]`? `jsonb` has a native array format internally. It doesn't make sense to use a PostgreSQL array of `jsonb` values.

Comment: basically i want an array of JSONB values. some users may have more interests than others. and I need to append this information to a user every time they add data regarding a specific interest. I could not find too much info regarding JSONB[], but it sounds like an array of JSONB values. I suppose I can contain my JSON in surrounding curly braces {} and try to append this structure each time instead of overwriting it. I will try this suggestion

Comment: but *json has arrays*. Just provide a  *single* jsonb, where the top level element is a json array containing json objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many frameworks don't support SQL arrays. There's an SQL standard for arrays but most clients have partial support or no support at all for it.

In PostgreSQL `type[]` is an array of `type`. So `jsonb[]` is an array of `jsonb`. Your client does not appear to understand this - either it doesn't support arrays, or it has special-cased array support on a per-data-type basis.

Luckily, you don't *need* a SQL array of `jsonb`, because `jsonb` stores [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) the JavaScript Serialized Object Notation. JSON defines both objects and arrays. So you can have an array of objects *inside the `jsonb` field*. No need for SQL arrays.

This is an SQL array of `jsonb` values, where each `jsonb` value is a single object (dictionary):

```
test=> SELECT ARRAY[
           '{ "x": 1, "y": 2 }',
           '{ "a": 3, "b": 4 }'
        ] :: jsonb[];
                        array                        
-----------------------------------------------------
 {"{ \"x\": 1, \"y\": 2 }","{ \"a\": 3, \"b\": 4 }"}
(1 row)
```

It has the data type `jsonb[]`. Note the use of the PostgreSQL `ARRAY[...]` constructor notation, and note that the `'string literals'` containing the `json` objects are *inside* the array.

This is a single `jsonb` field, containing an array of objects:

```
test=> SELECT 
'
        [
                { "x": 1, "y": 2 },
                { "a": 3, "b": 4 }
        ]
' :: jsonb;
                jsonb                 
--------------------------------------
 [{"x": 1, "y": 2}, {"a": 3, "b": 4}]
(1 row)
```

Note that it's a single string literal containing a json-serialization of an array of objects.

Comment: yeah thank you for this! unfortunately it looks like its not so easy to just append this structure using postgres as i've been reading on some other posts on stack, notably this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26703476/how-to-perform-update-operations-on-columns-of-type-jsonb-in-postgres-9-4
i may try to store this profile data in another layer such as redis or something that allows JSON updates in a more functionally manageble way

Comment: You can implement support for custom DB parameter, as indicated on the [documentation](https://github.com/playframework/anorm/blob/master/docs/manual/working/scalaGuide/main/sql/ScalaAnorm.md#parameters).

Comment: @kinghenry14 PostgreSQL continues to add more functions for manipulating json in new versions and there's also PL/V8. Working with it in-db does remain a bit limited.

Comment: my workaround for now simply is to retrieve the current values in SQL concatenate the string-ified response with the next object i want to add and then call the insert into column function again